# Shading a kernel density plot between two points.

Tags: r, plot

I frequently use kernel density plots to illustrate distributions. These are easy and fast to create in R like so:

```
set.seed(1)
draws <- rnorm(100)^2
dens <- density(draws)
plot(dens)
#or in one line like this: plot(density(rnorm(100)^2))
```

Which gives me this nice little PDF:

[image]

I'd like to shade the area under the PDF from the 75th to 95th percentiles. It's easy to calculate the points using the `quantile` function:

```
q75 <- quantile(draws, .75)
q95 <- quantile(draws, .95)
```

But how do I shade the the area between `q75` and `q95`?

Comment: Can you provide example of shading the outside of your range versus the inside of your range? Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

With the `polygon()` function, see its help page and I believe we had similar questions here too.

You need to find the index of the quantile values to get the actual `(x,y)` pairs.

*Edit:*  Here you go:

```
x1 <- min(which(dens$x >= q75))  
x2 <- max(which(dens$x <  q95))
with(dens, polygon(x=c(x[c(x1,x1:x2,x2)]), y= c(0, y[x1:x2], 0), col="gray"))
```

Output (added by JDL)

[image]

Comment: I never would have gotten that to work if you had not provided the structure. Thanks!

Comment: It's one of those things ... that have been in `demo(graphics)` since before the dawn on time so one comes across every now and then. Same idea for NBER regression shading etc.

Comment: ohhhh. I KNEW I had seen it somewhere but could not pull from my mental index where I had seen it. I'm glad your mental index is better than mine.

Answer (score 74):

Another solution:

```
dd <- with(dens,data.frame(x,y))

library(ggplot2)

qplot(x,y,data=dd,geom="line")+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(dd,x>q75 & x<q95),aes(ymax=y),ymin=0,
              fill="red",colour=NA,alpha=0.5)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 24):

An expanded solution:

If you wanted to shade both tails (copy & paste of Dirk's code) and use known x values:

```
set.seed(1)
draws <- rnorm(100)^2
dens <- density(draws)
plot(dens)

q2     <- 2
q65    <- 6.5
qn08   <- -0.8
qn02   <- -0.2

x1 <- min(which(dens$x >= q2))  
x2 <- max(which(dens$x <  q65))
x3 <- min(which(dens$x >= qn08))  
x4 <- max(which(dens$x <  qn02))

with(dens, polygon(x=c(x[c(x1,x1:x2,x2)]), y= c(0, y[x1:x2], 0), col="gray"))
with(dens, polygon(x=c(x[c(x3,x3:x4,x4)]), y= c(0, y[x3:x4], 0), col="gray"))
```

Result:

[image: 2-tailed poly]

Comment: I have the png file and hosted it on freeimagehosting, and it may not be loading because ... I'm  not sure.

Comment: Very blurry file.  Can you please recreate it and *upload it here directly* SO has its own servers service for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how to upload it to SO directly.

Answer (score 21):

This question needs a `lattice` answer. Here's a very basic one, simply adapting the method employed by Dirk and others:

```
#Set up the data
set.seed(1)
draws <- rnorm(100)^2
dens <- density(draws)

#Put in a simple data frame   
d <- data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)

#Define a custom panel function;
# Options like color don't need to be hard coded    
shadePanel <- function(x,y,shadeLims){
    panel.lines(x,y)
    m1 <- min(which(x >= shadeLims[1]))
    m2 <- max(which(x <= shadeLims[2]))
    tmp <- data.frame(x1 = x[c(m1,m1:m2,m2)], y1 = c(0,y[m1:m2],0))
    panel.polygon(tmp$x1,tmp$y1,col = "blue")
}

#Plot
xyplot(y~x,data = d, panel = shadePanel, shadeLims = c(1,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another `ggplot2` variant based on a function that approximates the kernel density at the original data values:

```r
approxdens <- function(x) {
    dens <- density(x)
    f <- with(dens, approxfun(x, y))
    f(x)
}
```

[image]

Using the original data (rather than producing a new data frame with the density estimate's x and y values) has the benefit of also working in faceted plots where the quantile values depend on the variable by which the data is being grouped:

[image]

**Code used**

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

# dummy data
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e2
dt <- tibble(value = rnorm(n)^2)

# function that approximates the density at the provided values
approxdens <- function(x) {
    dens <- density(x)
    f <- with(dens, approxfun(x, y))
    f(x)
}

probs <- c(0.75, 0.95)

dt <- dt %>%
    mutate(dy = approxdens(value),                         # calculate density
           p = percent_rank(value),                        # percentile rank 
           pcat = as.factor(cut(p, breaks = probs,         # percentile category based on probs
                                include.lowest = TRUE)))

ggplot(dt, aes(value, dy)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = dy, fill = pcat)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_fill_brewer(guide = "none") +
    theme_bw()



# dummy data with 2 groups
dt2 <- tibble(category = c(rep("A", n), rep("B", n)),
              value = c(rnorm(n)^2, rnorm(n, mean = 2)))

dt2 <- dt2 %>%
    group_by(category) %>% 
    mutate(dy = approxdens(value),    
           p = percent_rank(value),
           pcat = as.factor(cut(p, breaks = probs,
                                include.lowest = TRUE)))

# faceted plot
ggplot(dt2, aes(value, dy)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = dy, fill = pcat)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ category, nrow = 2, scales = "fixed") +
    scale_fill_brewer(guide = "none") +
    theme_bw()
```

Created on 2018-07-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).