# plot the *shaded* region under *y=sin(x)* in R

Tags: r

I would like to plot the *shaded* region between *y=sin(x)* and *y=0* over *x in [0, pi]* in R. Can you give some examples?

By *shaded*, I mean the region can be colored and better be half-transparent.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What's the shaded region? We can't see whatever you're looking at.

Comment: By shaded, I mean the region can be colored and better be half-transparent.

Comment: That's a repeat -- I once explained the same to JD -- see eg here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/r-shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see ?polygon :

```
x <- seq(0,pi,length.out=100)
y <- sin(x)

plot(x,y,type="l")
polygon(x,y,col="grey")
```

Comment: Correct. See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/r-shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points and I think I even had an answer where it was between tow curves.

Comment: @Dirk : thx for the pointer, I wasn't aware. voted to close the question.