# Plot sine curve in R

Tags: r, plot, gnuplot

How can I plot a generic *sin* curve in R? 
Based on the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369400/plot-the-shaded-region-under-y-sinx-in-r), I tried:

```
x <- seq(0,pi,length.out=100)
y <- sin(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

[image]

Actually what I really would is this graph, produced by `gnuplot`:

```
plot sin(x) linestyle 1
```

[image]

Furthermore, I would like to know why `gnuplot` produces a graph even if I do not assign any value to the variable `x`. Does it have a preassigned value or something else?

Comment: Did my answer actually answer your question? About the gnuplot question, so it is pretty normal to have standard settings. For me the graph looks like it is going until infinity but the edges of the canvas are at +-10...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`pi` is just one half of a sine curve... add more `pi` so you will get more curves...

```
x <- seq(0,8*pi,length.out=100)
y <- sin(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

Comment: If y is a function of x, you can use `curve` if you like: `curve(sin, to = 2*pi)`

Comment: Thank you everybody for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(sin, 0, 2*pi)
```

Change the multiplier to change the "frequency."