# ggplot2 - Shade area above line

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I have some data that is constrained below a 1:1 line.  I would to demonstrate this on a plot by lightly shading the area ABOVE the line, to draw the attention of the viewer to the area beneath the line.

I'm using `qplot` to generate the graphs.  Quickly, I have;

`qplot(x,y)+geom_abline(slope=1)`

but for the life of me, can't figure out how to easily shade the above area without plotting a separate object.  Is there an easy fix for this?

---

**EDIT**

Ok, Joran, here is an example data set:

```
 df=data.frame(x=runif(6,-2,2),y=runif(6,-2,2),
   var1=rep(c("A","B"),3),var2=rep(c("C","D"),3))
 df_poly=data.frame(x=c(-Inf, Inf, -Inf),y=c(-Inf, Inf, Inf))
```

and here is the code that I'm using to plot it (I took your advice and have been looking up `ggplot()`):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=var1))+
 facet_wrap(~var2)+
 geom_abline(slope=1,intercept=0,lwd=0.5)+
 geom_point(size=3)+
 scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
 geom_polygon(data=df_poly,aes(x,y),fill="blue",alpha=0.2)
```

The error kicked back is: "object 'var1' not found"  Something tells me that I'm implementing the argument incorrectly...

Comment: Coloring points and filling polygons are handled by two different aesthetics (colour and fill) and should not conflict, so I suspect you may be doing something wrong there. I'd be happy to help some more but I can't without a specific reproducible example of the data you're trying to plot...

Comment: Done.  I suspect this stems from my unfamiliarity with how ggplot2 handles such things.  Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Move `color = var1` to `geom_point`: `geom_point(aes(color=var1),...)`. Also, if you want different filled polygons in each facet be aware that you'll have to create a separate data frame for each facet and combine them into a single data frame including the `var2` factor, so `ggplot` knows which one to apply to each facet.

Comment: I updated my answer using your example data; hope that helps...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Building on @Andrie's answer here is a more (but not completely) general solution that handles shading above or below a given line in most cases.

I did not use the method that @Andrie referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786982/shaded-area-under-two-curves-using-r/6787479#6787479) since I ran into issues with `ggplot`'s tendency to automatically extend the plot extents when you add points near the edges. Instead, this builds the polygon points manually using `Inf` and `-Inf` as needed. A few notes:

- The points have to be in the 'correct' order in the data frame, since `ggplot` plots the polygon in the order that the points appear. So it's not enough to get the vertices of the polygon, they must be ordered (either clockwise or counterclockwise) as well.
- This solution assumes that the line you are plotting does not itself cause `ggplot` to extend the plot range. You'll see in my example that I pick a line to draw by randomly choosing two points in the data and drawing the line through them. If you try to draw a line too far away from the rest of you points, `ggplot` will automatically alter the plot ranges, and it becomes hard to predict what they will be.

First, here's the function that builds the polygon data frame:

```
buildPoly <- function(xr, yr, slope = 1, intercept = 0, above = TRUE){
    #Assumes ggplot default of expand = c(0.05,0)
    xrTru <- xr + 0.05*diff(xr)*c(-1,1)
    yrTru <- yr + 0.05*diff(yr)*c(-1,1)

    #Find where the line crosses the plot edges
    yCross <- (yrTru - intercept) / slope
    xCross <- (slope * xrTru) + intercept

    #Build polygon by cases
    if (above & (slope >= 0)){
        rs <- data.frame(x=-Inf,y=Inf)
        if (xCross[1] < yrTru[1]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,-Inf),c(yCross[1],-Inf))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
        }
        if (xCross[2] < yrTru[2]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]),c(Inf,Inf))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[2],Inf))
        }
    }
    if (!above & (slope >= 0)){
        rs <- data.frame(x= Inf,y= -Inf)
        if (xCross[1] > yrTru[1]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,-Inf),c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[1],-Inf))
        }
        if (xCross[2] > yrTru[2]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[2],Inf),c(Inf,Inf))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]))
        }
    }
    if (above & (slope < 0)){
        rs <- data.frame(x=Inf,y=Inf)
        if (xCross[1] < yrTru[2]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,Inf),c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[2],Inf))
        }
        if (xCross[2] < yrTru[1]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[1],-Inf),c(Inf,-Inf))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]))
        }
    }
    if (!above & (slope < 0)){
        rs <- data.frame(x= -Inf,y= -Inf)
        if (xCross[1] > yrTru[2]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,Inf),c(yCross[2],Inf))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
        }
        if (xCross[2] > yrTru[1]){
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]),c(Inf,-Inf))
        }
        else{
            rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[1],-Inf))
        }
    }

    return(rs)
}
```

It expects the x and y ranges of your data (as in `range()`), the slope and intercept of the line you are going to plot, and whether you want to shade above or below the line. Here's the code I used to generate the following four examples:

```
#Generate some data
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))

#Select two of the points to define the line
pts <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),size=2,replace=FALSE),]

#Slope and intercept of line through those points
sl <- diff(pts$y) / diff(pts$x)
int <- pts$y[1] - (sl*pts$x[1])

#Build the polygon
datPoly <- buildPoly(range(dat$x),range(dat$y),
            slope=sl,intercept=int,above=FALSE)

#Make the plot
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        geom_abline(slope=sl,intercept = int) +
        geom_polygon(data=datPoly,aes(x=x,y=y),alpha=0.2,fill="blue")
print(p)
```

And here are some examples of the results. If you find any bugs, of course, let me know so that I can update this answer...

[image: shade_above1]

[image: shade_above2]

[image: shade_below1]

[image: shade_below2]

**EDIT**

Updated to illustrate solution using OP's example data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(6,-2,2),y=runif(6,-2,2),
        var1=rep(c("A","B"),3),var2=rep(c("C","D"),3))
#Create polygon data frame
df_poly <- buildPoly(range(dat$x),range(dat$y))

ggplot(data=dat,aes(x,y)) + 
    facet_wrap(~var2) +
    geom_abline(slope=1,intercept=0,lwd=0.5)+
    geom_point(aes(colour=var1),size=3) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
    geom_polygon(data=df_poly,aes(x,y),fill="blue",alpha=0.2)
```

and this produces the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know there is no other way other than creating a polygon with alpha-blended fill.  For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1, y=1)
df_poly <- data.frame(
    x=c(-Inf, Inf, -Inf),
    y=c(-Inf, Inf, Inf)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_blank() + 
    geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) + 
    geom_polygon(data=df_poly, aes(x, y), fill="blue", alpha=0.2) +
```

[image]

Comment: Things get much more complicated if the line doesn't run from corner to corner, which is likely to happen if the line if plotted on top of another data set. I tinkered for a bit but couldn't come up with a general solution.

Comment: The general solution should be along the lines as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786982/shaded-area-under-two-curves-using-r/6787479#6787479

Comment: Thanks for your solutions!  I tried Andrie's, but I've specified that the points be colored by a third variable `qplot(x,y,color=z)`, which doesn't play nice with the `geom_polygon()` statement.  The line is also skewed lower than origin, which I can't figure out.  Any ideas?

Comment: The `colour` parameter usually controls the line colour.  You need to specify `fill` to change the inside of a polygon.

Comment: @jslefche I pieced together an answer that does this a bit more generally (for lines, at least)...

Answer (score 9):

One easy way to do this is to use `geom_ribbon` with the `ymax` value set to `Inf`, and the `ymin` value calculated by `stat_function`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

myfun  <- function(x) x
myfun2 <- function(x) x^2

ggplot() +
  geom_function(fun = myfun) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = 'function', fun = myfun,
              mapping = aes(ymin = after_stat(y), ymax = Inf),
              fill = 'lightblue', alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_function(fun = myfun2) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = 'function', fun = myfun2,
              mapping = aes(ymin = after_stat(y), ymax = Inf),
              fill = 'lightblue', alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: almost inclined to give you the bounty immediately ;)

Comment: @tjebo I'm honestly not looking for a bounty. It was very community-minded of you to offer one,  but I thought it would be good to add this answer here for Malvika, since the other options here are fairly...involved.

Answer (score 5):

Based on a minimally modified version of [@joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809174/1870254):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

buildPoly <- function(slope, intercept, above, xr, yr){
  # By Joran Elias, @joran https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809174/1870254
  #Find where the line crosses the plot edges
  yCross <- (yr - intercept) / slope
  xCross <- (slope * xr) + intercept

  #Build polygon by cases
  if (above & (slope >= 0)){
    rs <- data.frame(x=-Inf,y=Inf)
    if (xCross[1] < yr[1]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,-Inf),c(yCross[1],-Inf))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
    }
    if (xCross[2] < yr[2]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]),c(Inf,Inf))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[2],Inf))
    }
  }
  if (!above & (slope >= 0)){
    rs <- data.frame(x= Inf,y= -Inf)
    if (xCross[1] > yr[1]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,-Inf),c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[1],-Inf))
    }
    if (xCross[2] > yr[2]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[2],Inf),c(Inf,Inf))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]))
    }
  }
  if (above & (slope < 0)){
    rs <- data.frame(x=Inf,y=Inf)
    if (xCross[1] < yr[2]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,Inf),c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[2],Inf))
    }
    if (xCross[2] < yr[1]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[1],-Inf),c(Inf,-Inf))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]))
    }
  }
  if (!above & (slope < 0)){
    rs <- data.frame(x= -Inf,y= -Inf)
    if (xCross[1] > yr[2]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,Inf),c(yCross[2],Inf))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(-Inf,xCross[1]))
    }
    if (xCross[2] > yr[1]){
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(Inf,xCross[2]),c(Inf,-Inf))
    }
    else{
      rs <- rbind(rs,c(yCross[1],-Inf))
    }
  }
  return(rs)
}
```

you can also [extend ggplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) like this:

```
GeomSection <- ggproto("GeomSection", GeomPolygon, 
  default_aes = list(fill="blue", size=0, alpha=0.2, colour=NA, linetype="dashed"), 
  required_aes = c("slope", "intercept", "above"),
  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
    ranges <- coord$backtransform_range(panel_params)
    data$group <- seq_len(nrow(data))
    data <- data %>% group_by_all %>% do(buildPoly(.$slope, .$intercept, .$above, ranges$x, ranges$y)) %>% unnest
    GeomPolygon$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord)
    }
  )

geom_section <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, ..., slope, intercept, above, 
          na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA) {
  if (missing(mapping) && missing(slope) && missing(intercept) && missing(above)) {
    slope <- 1
    intercept <- 0
    above <- TRUE
  }
  if (!missing(slope) || !missing(intercept)|| !missing(above)) {
    if (missing(slope)) 
      slope <- 1
    if (missing(intercept)) 
      intercept <- 0
    if (missing(above)) 
      above <- TRUE
    data <- data.frame(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, above=above)
    mapping <- aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, above=above)
    show.legend <- FALSE
  }
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatIdentity, 
        geom = GeomSection, position = PositionIdentity, show.legend = show.legend, 
        inherit.aes = FALSE, params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

To be able to use it as easily as a geom_abline:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(6,-2,2),y=runif(6,-2,2),
                  var1=rep(c("A","B"),3),var2=rep(c("C","D"),3))

ggplot(data=dat,aes(x,y)) + 
  facet_wrap(~var2) +
  geom_abline(slope=1,intercept=0,lwd=0.5)+
  geom_point(aes(colour=var1),size=3) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
  geom_section(slope=1, intercept=0, above=TRUE)
```

[image: two facets with points and a section of the plot areas hihlighted]

This variant has the additional advantage that it also works with multiple slopes and non-default limit expansions.

```
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x,y)) +
  facet_wrap(~var2) +
  geom_abline(slope=1,intercept=0,lwd=0.5)+
  geom_point(aes(colour=var1),size=3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
  geom_section(data=data.frame(slope=c(-1,1), above=c(FALSE,TRUE), selected=c("selected","selected 2")), 
               aes(slope=slope, above=above, intercept=0, fill=selected), size=1) +
  expand_limits(x=3)
```

[image: as above but with two highlighted areas and expanded limits]

Comment: Thanks for quite a fantastic answer to an old question. :-)