# Add straight line to a plot

Tags: r, plot, line

How can I add a straight line form (5, 5) to infinity to this plot? I use abline but I do not want the line between 5 to 5, just I need after 5 to infinity.

```
x <- c(1:5); y <- x
plot(x, y, type="l")
abline(v= max(x), col="black", lwd=2, lty=2)
```

Comment: How do you represent infinity in a plot?  Why not just plot `[5, ymax]`

Comment: Really? Infinity on a plot? Please explain why this is a meaningful request.

Comment: @Dwin - admittedly, you can use `Inf` and `-Inf` in `ggplot` - as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801571/ggplot2-shade-area-above-line

Comment: Amusing, ... but really not what was articulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `segments` and `par('usr')` to extract the existing axis limits. I've used `lty=1` to show that it wil extend to the edge of the plotting area

```
 plot(x,y,type = 'l')
 segments(x0 = max(x), y0 = max(y), y1 = par('usr')[4], lwd=2)
```

[image]