# Fill area under a curve that does not overlap any other curves

Tags: r, plot, polygon, fill

This questions somewhat relates to [a question I previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29419479/4200318). However, I have narrowed down exactly what I am trying to do and I feel this question is different enough from my previous question to warrant a new post.

I am adding multiple (>50) curves to a plot in R. Each curve has a corresponding probability (0-1). I have sorted the curves by probability and would like to shade the area under each curve with a transparency `alpha` weighted by probability.

I am adding the plots in a descending sequence by probability. I would like to shade *just* the portion under each curve that is not covered by any curves currently on the graph.

I have read many posts on shading areas between curves, or under curves, but I cannot figure out how to shade *just* the area not covered by any other plot on the graph. I hope this is not considered a duplicate.

1. [Shaded area under two curves using R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6786982/4200318)
2. [Shading a kernel density 
   plot between two points.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)
3. [How to make gradient color filled

   timeseries plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250542/how-to-make-gradient-color-filled-timeseries-plot-in-r)
4. [Shading between curves in R](http://www.alisonsinclair.ca/2011/03/shading-between-curves-in-r/)

Here is an example picture (marked up in MS paint) of what I would like a final plot to look like (except without the lines inside the polygons). I used four curves in this example, but I will be adding many more when I figure this out. I added the curve with the highest response first, then each subsequent curve, shading just the portion not already filled.

[image]

In the above example I used `lines` to add the curves to the graph and then shaded them in MS paint. I understand to fill in the area under each curve I will need to use `polygon` with `border=NA` .Here is an example of how I am planning on using polygon to shade based on the response value. My current approach is to adjust the color using `alpha`, but if there is a more practical approach using a gray scale pallet or gradient I am open to suggestions.

`polygon(x, y1,col=rgb(0,0,0,alpha=(1-wei.param[1,3])), border=NA )`

I have tried several different approaches (based on the above hyperlinks) to specify the dimensions of each polygon. I can get it to work for polygons 1-3, but after that they start stacking on top of each other.

Here are example data and code to reproduce the plots.

```
diameters<-c(rep(1.5,393),3,3,3,3,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4,
            3.4,3.4,3.4,3.5,3.5,3.6,3.6,3.7,3.7,3.7,3.7,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,
            3.9,3.9,4,4,4,4.1,4.2,4.2,4.2,4.2,4.3,4.3,4.4,4.49,4.5,4.5,4.6,4.7,
            4.7,4.7,4.8,4.9,4.9,4.9,5,5,5,5,5.1,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.4,5.6,5.7,5.7,
            5.7,5.8,6,6,6,6.3,6.4,6.6,6.9,6.9,6.9,7,7.1,7.2,7.4,7.4,7.7,7.8,7.9,
            7.9,8.2,8.5,8.5,8.9,9.2,10.2,10.47,10.5,10.7,11.7,13.2,13.5,14.4,14.5,
            14.5,15.1,18.4)

wei.param<-matrix(data=NA,nrow=5,ncol=3,dimnames = list(c(),c("shape", "scale", "prob")))
wei.param[,1]<-c(1.834682,2.720390,3.073429,1.9,1.9)
wei.param[,2]<-c(2.78,2.78,2.78,1.6,2.8710692)
wei.param[,3]<-c(0.49, 0.46, 0.26, 0.26, 0.07)

x=seq(0,20,1)
y1<-dweibull(x,shape=wei.param[1,1],scale=wei.param[1,2])
y2<-dweibull(x,shape=wei.param[2,1],scale=wei.param[2,2])
y3<-dweibull(x,shape=wei.param[3,1],scale=wei.param[3,2])
y4<-dweibull(x,shape=wei.param[4,1],scale=wei.param[4,2])

#Plot
hist(diameters,freq=F,main='',ylim=c(0,.5))

polygon(x, y1,col=rgb(0,0,0,alpha=(1-wei.param[1,3])), border=NA )

lines(x, y1)
lines(x, y2)
lines(x, y3)
lines(x, y4)
```

Comment: if you just remove the transparency, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @GNG The trick is to add a white polygon behind your color polygons. Also, as a long term programing goal, I would suggest learning `ggplot'.

Comment: Also, @GNG, good job with a reproducible question!

Comment: @RichardErickson It seems 'ggplot' is the solution to many graphical questions I search for. I need to stop dragging my feet and become familiar with it. Thanks, sometimes I don't know exactly what I want to ask, but I figure if I show what I've read and give a good example experts our there can understand what I am trying to do. I appreciate your help; I will give it a run through then accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you want:

[image]

I don't know how to do this with base `R` graphics, but here's the code for `ggplot2`, which I know better. Note that `ggplot2` requires data to be input as a `data.frame`. Also, I created a second probability column so that I could `group` the polygons with `ggplot2`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(x, 4), y = c(y1, y2, y3, y4), 
                Prob = c(
                rep(wei.param[1,3], length(y1)),
                rep(wei.param[2,3], length(y2)),
                rep(wei.param[2,3], length(y2)),
                rep(wei.param[4,3], length(y4))))

df$Prob2 = as.factor(df$Prob)
library(scales) # needed for alpha function with ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

example <- ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(aes(x = diameters, y = ..density..), 
                prob = TRUE, fill = alpha('white', 0), color = 'black') +
    geom_polygon(data = df, aes( x = x, y = y), color = 'white', 
                 fill = 'white') +
    geom_polygon(data = df, aes( x = x, y = y, alpha = Prob, 
                 group = Prob2)) +
    geom_polygon() + theme_bw()
ggsave('example.jpg', example, width = 6, height = 4)
```

You should be able to do a similar trick with `base` `R`. All you need to do is plot the white polygons over your histogram, but under your shaded polygons. If you decide to use my `ggplot2` code you'll probably want to tweak bin width (see `?geom_histogram` for details about how to do this).