# shading a limited part of the overlap of two curves in R

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I see a great answer for drawing a polygon at the overlap of two curves [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787419/7223434). But I wonder what if we want to shade part of (*not the entire of*) the overlap limited between say `0` and `2` (*as shown in the pic below*)?

I tried the following without success:

```
a <- curve(dnorm(x), -4, 6, panel.l = abline(v = c(0, 2), col = 1:2))
b <- curve(dnorm(x, 2), add = TRUE, col = 2)

x <- a$x[a$x >= 0 & a$x <= 2]

polygon(x, c(a$y[x], b$y[x]), col = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idea is to give proper vertices.
`a$y[x]` is wrong as x does not hold indices but values.

Instead you want to find the intersection by pairwise minimum function and further subset it to fit within desired range.
`pmin(a$y, b$y)[a$x >= xaxis_cut_1 & a$x <= xaxis_cut_2]`

You also want to account for some free vertices that get excluded from above intersection hence append the x and y vectors accordingly.

```
x = c(xaxis_cut_1,a$x[a$x >= 0 & a$x <= 2],xaxis_cut_2)
y = c(0, pmin(a$y, b$y)[a$x >= xaxis_cut_1 & a$x <= xaxis_cut_2],0 )
```

Full code

```
# your points on xaxis:
xaxis_cut_1 = 0 ; xaxis_cut_2 = 2 ; 

# your code for curves
a <- curve(dnorm(x), -4, 6, panel.l = abline(v = c(xaxis_cut_1, xaxis_cut_2), col = 1:2))
b <- curve(dnorm(x, 2), add = TRUE, col = 2)

# calculate the desired area with a pairwise min or max function (pmin / pmax). subset the curve values on the basis of your desired x-axis range

polygon(x, y, col = 4)
```

[here is the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvXG8.png)