# graph 95th percentile

Tags: r

I have a time series data that can plot using:

```
plot(x$numbers, type="l", col="blue")
```

I like to get the 95th percentile and add this 95th percentile to this graph

```
x_percent<-quantile(x$numbers, 0.95)
```

How do I add x_percent to the existing graph of x$numbers?

```
x$numbers<-c(1,2,3,8,10,30)
x$percent<-quantile(x$numbers, 0.95)
plot(x$numbers, type="l")
```

here, I like to add the x$percent to the graph, basically draw a vertical line with the value of 95th percentile value.
andy ideas?

Comment: could you provide a sample of `x$numbers`, I am not sure what you mean by adding `x_percent`.  Do you mean marking where the 95th precintile range is?

Comment: I'm guessing... but I think you want `abline` however, I think you might not be plotting what you think you're plotting...

Comment: I just edited the original post.

Comment: This still isn't reproducible since we don't have the `data.frame` x.  however, my answer still holds.  look at `?abline`

Comment: you may find this insightful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok your edit didnt help much but I am guessing you're wanting to do something like this..(see Justins comments)

```
x   <- seq(0,20,length=1000)
y   <- dnorm(x,mean=10, sd=3)
plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=2)
abline(a=1,b=1,v=1,lty=3)
```

But your mention of time series makes me think you're not sure what you're plotting. Otherwise you would be simply marking the `abline` on a particular date.

[image]

PS I'm guessing you do want the line on the other side of the x axis