# draw the following shaded area in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shading a kernel density plot between two points.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)

How to draw this graph in R, assuming normal pdf?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for getting shaded area below:

```
plot(dnorm,-4,4,xlab="x",ylab="pdf")
xvals <- seq(-2,1,length=50)
dvals <- dnorm(xvals)
polygon(c(xvals,rev(xvals)),c(rep(0,50),rev(dvals)),col="gray")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1 There seems to be a minor red/grey issue here

Answer (score 6):

I answered that a while back [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points/3494767#3494767) for something closely related. The question really is a duplicate and should be closed.  All these *how do I shade below a curve* questions are answered by a close read of `help(polygon)` and a study of the existing examples.