# Combining facet_wrap and 95% area of density plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

This is the dataset of the example:

```
df <- structure(list(value = c(26.4560042847125, 11.3004326071196, 
26.0912039914014, 21.7564514051877, 19.1783781677091, 5.94421245322079, 
31.8413241458856, 17.8041397957644, 13.5068665088598, 17.9723844580366, 
18.413772723976, 25.191980817921, 12.1387271204975, 11.7442528298423, 
18.8426804497157, 18.2434801270149, 15.4599584446951, 14.4114064741345, 
5.20563740908386, 32.1307249122222, 20.9295615954846, 16.5414727911291, 
27.3585249215781, 24.6751049400156, 12.0355248232406, 5.80276414825542, 
16.4798506309038, 16.8151486409612, 11.9951744505088, 16.5767389311535, 
17.1422504961227, 13.1849814792352, 30.6863972928862, 18.7339671145281, 
15.2527855785239, 30.4559964651735, 15.4325281215311, 21.6285729773936, 
18.8212128863866, 19.8663104715395, 20.4649895706185, 21.085086958061, 
16.81611512833, 14.4101879578111, 10.194448355433, 15.0895007544837, 
13.0038446865497, 19.5295041641984, 18.9517255152942, 23.5287824654406, 
19.2954636419046, 14.5561943967062, 19.6380187004554, 12.4929211706024, 
15.3429057147136, 30.8711036362793, 6.34071258302185, 10.3030240482004, 
5.43286074241186, 28.0480052776744, 19.4672675467987, 7.01203010815595, 
16.5499263879614, 14.1482414746203, 29.9967961516366, 9.27729612295405, 
11.2527117390006, 13.8291258221135, 19.0154411538213, 19.5560962543118, 
22.108154803337, 6.41696214434401, 23.5113731413851, 39.1119494067263, 
16.9793263332382, 18.6129796336054, 14.6501691977102, 24.4230211327031, 
25.6701114670566, 17.0029527985508, 16.9849275468199, 9.9599552143325, 
16.5655151678492, 13.5278947227515, 31.15514441992, 8.72178029403942, 
16.312889713984, 19.3418539122578, 21.3313284882231, 11.8400527571333, 
14.998396950767, 25.7289732970782, 6.57314012467025, 11.1568258576261, 
21.1196535190717, 11.767182917672, 15.1931268586876, 18.7977871328672, 
21.5961497107114, 15.263309924513, 17.1474209264846, 14.1539718104681, 
13.1828248119332, 17.8153507807165, 6.42580610362336, 16.7583247096472, 
22.245486895896, 13.4727290121981, 14.5305370605891, 18.2580161222819, 
17.4014528282145, 13.2553733551967, 24.7009679914504, 22.0135120654588, 
16.4495319221989, 11.1353432141639, 10.5337363638627, 26.974641063225, 
7.38630916014468, 6.51530987317113, 5.81284385244122, 12.6677378570296, 
26.0448237730009, 6.32274204811341, 16.1904621738529, 4.89328225545913, 
16.4819166845575, 29.3511508316203, 5.40607244438725, 31.1939995902181, 
15.5739214325586, 15.7397880239972, 8.24761769290674, 20.9869118311111, 
16.570220351544, 16.3953654645265, 7.44293345349256, 10.9787676244162, 
9.10732992923047, 6.64915991419533, 10.5046687891058, 22.9597733582826, 
13.7100293406814, 16.4118264676316, 27.2912066959673, 19.8160501308633, 
8.4759491649634, 9.00103502966495, 15.5007176762628, 27.1774191959377, 
16.2447549001115, 15.7259565928727, 17.4156789266418, 15.8255000812014, 
28.6002273574716, 21.6379695122532, 22.6327836588976, 25.8557799246955, 
8.51730841554355, 17.7120478406703, 27.4423263663563, 13.4585655406126, 
16.0686843744779, 26.2006671116081, 15.7764175062066, 22.6938896600881, 
21.4847685658136, 19.3758357488278, 6.36349236177635, 5.00020901404707, 
15.2451463338252, 14.4535418073004, 8.67704803525262, 4.95624952414421, 
12.751166999427, 17.8172845253349, 16.4391843088573, 21.4154880850919, 
15.1575244596883, 21.5947609469574, 22.3522596713281, 12.2515147546865, 
28.7153293473618, 16.1544458359484, 16.4706868562516, 24.9854695915753, 
18.7212762429278, 7.02634452742885, 19.0191668519016, 20.5982779454464, 
25.8863396087814, 18.0493159974649, 27.4943122483041, 8.32868126419798, 
17.7575845873521, 16.8159529581999, 15.2904248830721, 17.7221762344958, 
12.0527319230593, 17.5394255133235, 17.08150461134, 17.4082051938374, 
31.0494513131031, 20.7042882829682, 13.4214170305262, 15.3443880390113, 
17.8822933550918, 15.8213305459621, 26.0955799091996, 24.5722668431543, 
4.62694194695913, 16.9033429520629, 18.4634880881409, 6.5609684004392, 
19.434043085004, 20.1293696316641, 14.3477752303996, 6.62392094948463, 
26.7365389159835, 14.4201734598866, 29.0684722830179, 21.6062005499429, 
10.8934199565188, 16.3606114676272, 30.2571028363976, 5.6496662852755, 
25.1986867984754, 21.4654887261337, 24.7332201830643, 5.2457700725677, 
19.6583336609293, 20.5545340061544, 15.5634242202726, 16.5408846722384, 
20.892080680959, 13.8915107851808, 25.0677779223962, 15.7718307201342, 
13.584838925397, 6.35107091261947, 16.0230046337498, 17.4483608897344, 
18.669621207412, 19.7744618342615, 20.7272351644467, 16.1705202522793, 
6.97277942823325, 12.5229538669431, 22.2275416676016, 13.1405541107555, 
28.7606943962085, 11.6280518733018, 26.3470942936772, 24.5068719428209, 
4.81749134072314, 17.5034706747253, 21.9487639690478, 14.9960021236818, 
8.83490321555611, 27.8449774596931, 14.5568710465123, 15.4927744289492, 
20.2717544423498, 18.2891606419708, 21.0396126076905, 21.1170885507942, 
7.03907255996405, 20.3233290926629, 18.6671559829201, 19.5238614201738, 
17.4251840704542, 17.5613187306229, 18.2925045809703, 7.61338551298722, 
27.2344543864653, 19.2553109039, 11.6430028274559, 14.8160577969252, 
16.8538479941789, 13.3729437240079, 14.175645822667, 22.4233943951559, 
16.4152209765634, 9.20471945799771, 15.1844727200093, 6.94605866653535, 
6.11311049306179, 17.6771142266354, 14.2062769178595, 14.2588961265756, 
22.7286169828866, 15.5706980161588, 19.0617127570505, 20.9698682527156, 
22.0858357850003, 9.43699415605619, 17.6945623836002, 6.17375671815648, 
19.5777221608472, 14.8213714741305, 12.4956568034577, 10.0515315798204, 
25.1185717497261, 14.2511356272247, 24.1937204102469, 13.8732147304708, 
15.1914967707697, 17.8884743481924, 17.308949627983, 19.8403405969443, 
6.27644917123959, 21.0476221011735, 42.909001525632, 13.282402176534, 
26.5660139438276, 4.8956068113101, 15.5170699327289, 21.1547254584194, 
18.2444449495958, 13.5641681379038, 10.7983536202868, 23.5613946309803, 
18.603762531108, 22.924614307613, 23.4704886313313, 31.2828034821204, 
4.82538112469637, 33.9580436335256, 3.87578395976413, 8.22746412392606, 
19.8910543525753, 21.4076839901007, 17.7189578414762, 11.8678635680228, 
13.2929035531615, 15.3205015239291, 5.52110950247512, 17.7684058933069, 
15.0354420649544, 27.7172210002907, 5.54848359113719, 16.9654502565518, 
8.51929980273464, 16.1990162754887, 16.9318786555617, 17.5790448090526, 
16.3640847216262, 22.6599675729007, 16.8931849008231, 17.2034202001854, 
18.1739593745264, 10.5233465228477, 15.3371918460196, 9.42139466521943, 
7.08575896485081, 17.5440976283031, 30.3035101039193, 18.4755982303901, 
18.1537240230732, 28.3007230195128, 16.3942662939621, 16.5024545648657, 
22.2323700056854, 16.9564287917509, 24.6408238115661, 18.7497384956859, 
15.2728564970259, 22.2792734068488, 6.59805006389384, 26.7959873566452, 
20.7417494062242, 22.1869332817044, 13.8526806709858, 16.0808016867551, 
18.9858302906166, 17.4410259067329, 21.2774167122479, 13.5726768559948, 
9.10062585702508, 19.1747864659422, 16.4988956408767, 28.8892724231888, 
22.3754245685937, 7.03454145175241, 21.2672490980755, 22.3493673995643, 
11.7906190025429, 5.80365931564078, 17.807453899569, 19.6630207802805, 
13.1191447712945, 18.3963620458804, 7.39229310264565, 22.5981592016531, 
9.17811194540908, 27.397244335604, 5.14426148943561, 38.5574616230177, 
30.2897674775767, 28.3192495642753, 21.6388186223199, 19.5151854167236, 
28.3531601053651, 5.94948573283536, 19.5615977954544, 16.7504773905214, 
31.3167846169049, 23.230403311226, 17.3537619812738, 14.962108856485, 
15.2689304659187, 22.7704986291791, 17.759555024491, 24.8991363169724, 
6.07175333365212, 10.1874795293905, 17.8254473354667, 7.94924888151089, 
21.1120609226263, 13.4437647435994, 30.5110840567013, 10.3181799863316, 
25.7885410399723, 17.6784567709022, 6.34597114564601, 20.8241615142547, 
17.5148932972187, 13.2119194122513, 11.2706091019527, 17.4408745415673, 
9.83971627622657, 18.5482063148611, 21.346454812652, 23.3067653830419, 
27.3234603168211, 8.98572717270548, 20.8903380161677, 26.3929074976724, 
6.22342510234302, 16.1595681727996, 31.1904015885113, 8.66329712806987, 
25.4971286636744, 31.2188745395857, 18.7257148455341, 7.79168068763096, 
6.09590647356107, 10.4006622706372, 17.1865312262143, 17.8349851317392, 
5.50606377288014, 20.0143589600239, 6.3518468206745, 8.21390763426873, 
7.14733094098492, 32.2538037585035, 13.6303864452124, 13.4340305843641, 
20.8386703808899, 21.1584033968823, 14.1731665527681, 5.25263777202797, 
20.822355197476, 14.7704270997013, 5.29318561900051, 4.66251417667295, 
14.6983122156846, 23.270582748804, 16.1732262356361, 44.7530848358461, 
22.4660659576001, 32.7694582959274, 5.94827950418212, 22.8078647242269, 
18.4976630271388, 20.2155463094745, 24.2941297176831, 12.3328372736094, 
17.9889862276501, 36.238326909562, 15.2438791683076, 27.5226032725564, 
7.37945853944159, 20.1831013798191, 21.1809794399302, 6.35459519595256, 
4.88103649114211, 16.0665680749314, 14.4073036432768, 12.2671796843314, 
10.1256783515929, 26.53075714629, 20.0678694075525, 15.5087614076527, 
25.9483091743902, 8.62949119758882, 11.6712347699932, 24.4205320480103, 
9.74330913523425, 18.7898082104659, 22.1810208127755, 21.7581592462825, 
25.5438505016225, 17.2174343350299, 29.2542613869547, 23.91127162509, 
16.2459311018909, 26.025384541416, 21.1162346958816, 16.1543562519731, 
16.202200427184, 19.5269010270757, 13.9809780557452, 16.9609103289252, 
24.1730606491254, 16.3147221556512, 10.5203452453814, 22.3587979671424, 
14.98465418348, 16.0612450647036, 16.4952755611921, 21.4565200001346, 
18.0615534069062, 15.7326772741547, 13.546862555628, 23.3445399194559, 
15.0989647823265, 12.2222331922134, 18.051780285404, 20.2237639018134, 
22.354365988062, 25.6707816303602, 9.88096592439327, 16.9931891787006, 
13.0817177893317, 14.7117812417113, 18.5165779734025, 33.3241511086258, 
11.9175275500509, 15.1416329261376, 12.5991435129264, 13.0915270348491, 
20.4732567160755, 27.3955310040586, 31.7179684999035, 26.6768842097533, 
21.7069783558196, 16.5218709535629, 20.6299668948804, 8.05387196286873, 
12.3151859808428, 20.8261265749177, 19.8739419868535, 19.5933138317485, 
18.9706241554932, 4.81733267458324, 27.9936084234279, 18.1927877797401, 
21.7878758075389, 14.7762540080605, 27.8067558245882, 23.6878108603069, 
22.5446729368314, 21.0826869583074, 18.9794052828778, 23.32572447268, 
30.7253078427685, 28.5711484145541, 26.9394620772799, 16.1834701176737, 
5.21852629413438, 18.0149522840495, 16.7509097613963, 25.1087179282088, 
6.48391843011999, 18.8528996228297, 19.0827782336775, 27.1691439250959, 
14.5844738667839, 10.1826908622265, 19.6992293565004, 16.5840641088384, 
29.7124637485905, 19.3963671830227, 18.0501889213426, 14.9796641903152, 
13.7030503226166, 16.2638893680864, 6.38587842771554, 18.8561740891013, 
29.2666661169771, 20.5625268483328, 16.8571978661081, 19.2477481451171, 
4.95989560432542, 21.6989943042097, 13.652337183121, 20.2332007932773, 
17.6066627101605, 13.560096930636), Var = c("Vc", "Vc", "Vr", 
"Vr", "EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "Vr", "AET", "OES", "OES", "EDJ", "Ve", 
"OES", "OES", "AET", "BS", "EDJ", "AET", "OES.EDJ", "Vr", "OES", 
"AET", "Ve", "Ve", "EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "AET", "EDJ", "RET", 
"AET", "AET", "Ve", "BS", "Vcdp", "Vr", "Vc", "Vc", "AET", "Vcdp", 
"RET", "Vcdp", "AET", "AET", "AET", "AET", "EDJ", "Vcdp", "RET", 
"RET", "RET", "EDJ", "OES", "EDJ", "OES", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "OES", 
"OES.EDJ", "Vc", "BS", "OES.EDJ", "BS", "OES", "Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", 
"Vcdp.Vc", "RET", "Ve", "AET", "BS", "OES.EDJ", "Ve", "Vr", "AET", 
"BS", "EDJ", "Vc", "Vr", "OES", "EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", "BS", 
"Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", "RET", "Vcdp", "Ve", "BS", "AET", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", 
"BS", "Vr", "Vcdp.Vc", "AET", "RET", "Vc", "EDJ", "Vc", "EDJ", 
"EDJ", "BS", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "BS", "EDJ", "BS", "Vc", "RET", 
"OES", "Vc", "Ve", "OES", "Vc", "Vcdp.Vc", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "OES.EDJ", 
"OES.EDJ", "AET", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "Ve", 
"OES.EDJ", "Ve", "RET", "BS", "Vcdp.Vc", "Ve", "RET", "BS", "Vcdp.Vc", 
"Vc", "Vcdp.Vc", "OES.EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vc", "AET", "BS", "Vcdp", 
"RET", "Vcdp.Vc", "OES", "BS", "Vr", "AET", "OES", "Vr", "RET", 
"Vc", "Vr", "Vc", "Vcdp", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vc", "Vcdp", "EDJ", "EDJ", 
"Ve", "AET", "Ve", "Vcdp", "RET", "OES.EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "RET", 
"AET", "Vcdp.Vc", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "Vr", "AET", "BS", "BS", 
"Vr", "Vc", "AET", "Ve", "RET", "RET", "Vc", "Vcdp", "OES.EDJ", 
"Vcdp", "BS", "Vr", "BS", "Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", "AET", "OES", "Ve", 
"RET", "BS", "EDJ", "RET", "EDJ", "Ve", "BS", "EDJ", "EDJ", "AET", 
"Vr", "Vc", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "BS", 
"EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "Ve", "EDJ", "Vr", "Vc", "OES", "AET", "Ve", 
"OES.EDJ", "Vc", "RET", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", "BS", "AET", "AET", 
"Vcdp", "Vr", "BS", "Vr", "EDJ", "AET", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "BS", 
"Vr", "Vc", "BS", "AET", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp", "OES", 
"Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "Vr", "OES", "Vcdp.Vc", 
"Vr", "Vc", "BS", "OES", "AET", "RET", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", "Vc", 
"RET", "RET", "AET", "OES", "EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp", "AET", 
"OES", "OES", "RET", "RET", "Vr", "Vc", "Vr", "Vcdp.Vc", "RET", 
"OES.EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "OES", "EDJ", "Vr", "RET", "BS", 
"BS", "Vr", "Vcdp.Vc", "AET", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "RET", "OES", 
"Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", "Vr", "Vc", "EDJ", "OES", "Vc", "BS", "Vc", 
"OES.EDJ", "Vcdp", "Vr", "OES", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", "OES", "Vc", 
"BS", "Vc", "Vr", "Vc", "OES", "Vc", "RET", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", 
"Vr", "OES.EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", "RET", "Ve", "Vr", "AET", "AET", 
"OES.EDJ", "Ve", "EDJ", "Vr", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vc", 
"BS", "Ve", "AET", "RET", "AET", "AET", "RET", "Vcdp.Vc", "EDJ", 
"Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp.Vc", "RET", "Vcdp", "EDJ", "OES", "Ve", "BS", 
"Ve", "Ve", "EDJ", "Ve", "AET", "BS", "BS", "OES.EDJ", "Ve", 
"BS", "Vc", "EDJ", "OES", "Vr", "Ve", "RET", "Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", 
"Vcdp", "RET", "Vc", "Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp", "BS", "OES", "OES.EDJ", 
"Vc", "AET", "BS", "EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", 
"Vr", "Ve", "BS", "Vr", "AET", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "Vc", "EDJ", 
"Vcdp", "BS", "Ve", "AET", "EDJ", "RET", "RET", "BS", "OES.EDJ", 
"OES", "Vcdp", "Vcdp.Vc", "BS", "OES", "Ve", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", 
"OES", "Vcdp.Vc", "RET", "OES", "AET", "Vcdp.Vc", "OES", "Vcdp.Vc", 
"Vr", "BS", "Ve", "Vr", "Vcdp.Vc", "RET", "Ve", "OES.EDJ", "Vr", 
"Vr", "Vcdp.Vc", "Ve", "Ve", "Vcdp", "OES", "OES.EDJ", "OES", 
"AET", "AET", "OES.EDJ", "BS", "OES.EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp.Vc", 
"Vcdp", "AET", "OES", "Vcdp", "AET", "RET", "OES.EDJ", "AET", 
"Vc", "OES.EDJ", "OES.EDJ", "AET", "Vr", "Vcdp", "Vr", "RET", 
"Vr", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", "OES", "Vcdp", "Vcdp", "Vr", "AET", "Vr", 
"OES", "Vcdp", "Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp", "Vr", "OES.EDJ", "OES.EDJ", 
"AET", "EDJ", "Vcdp.Vc", "AET", "Vcdp", "Vc", "EDJ", "Ve", "Vr", 
"OES", "Ve", "OES", "BS", "BS", "Vr", "Ve", "Ve", "Vcdp", "Vcdp", 
"EDJ", "Vc", "OES", "BS", "AET", "AET", "EDJ", "Vr", "Vr", "BS", 
"Vcdp.Vc", "Vr", "Vc", "RET", "RET", "AET", "AET", "OES", "OES", 
"Ve", "RET", "EDJ", "AET", "Vc", "Ve", "Vcdp", "Vcdp.Vc", "AET", 
"RET", "Vc", "BS", "Vc", "EDJ", "Vc", "OES", "AET", "Vc", "Ve", 
"Vr", "Ve", "Ve", "OES", "RET", "Vcdp.Vc", "OES", "EDJ", "EDJ", 
"RET", "RET", "OES.EDJ", "Vcdp", "EDJ", "BS", "RET", "Ve", "Vr", 
"Ve", "AET", "BS", "BS", "Ve", "Ve", "Vr", "RET", "OES.EDJ", 
"RET", "AET", "Vcdp", "OES.EDJ", "EDJ", "Vcdp", "Ve", "AET", 
"Vcdp.Vc", "Vcdp", "AET", "Vc", "AET", "Vc", "BS", "BS", "EDJ", 
"OES.EDJ", "OES", "Vcdp", "AET", "AET", "Vc", "OES.EDJ", "BS", 
"RET", "AET", "RET", "OES")), .Names = c("value", "Var"), row.names = c(847L, 
815L, 1151L, 1894L, 4219L, 10951L, 1854L, 7297L, 5228L, 5492L, 
4913L, 2514L, 5151L, 5542L, 7329L, 6130L, 4071L, 7696L, 10703L, 
1381L, 5661L, 7515L, 2420L, 2852L, 4368L, 10769L, 7647L, 7749L, 
4611L, 8610L, 7934L, 7353L, 2497L, 6160L, 3382L, 1685L, 285L, 
907L, 7880L, 3293L, 8167L, 3339L, 7539L, 7438L, 7519L, 7811L, 
4042L, 3149L, 8911L, 8866L, 8602L, 4580L, 5013L, 4231L, 5064L, 
2231L, 10146L, 5036L, 10770L, 174L, 6855L, 10352L, 6350L, 5955L, 
2133L, 9824L, 9395L, 8812L, 2884L, 7849L, 6649L, 10640L, 2400L, 
1859L, 7062L, 6311L, 4390L, 900L, 1448L, 5987L, 4665L, 9570L, 
1784L, 6973L, 2671L, 9239L, 8172L, 3336L, 2489L, 6281L, 7833L, 
879L, 10458L, 6046L, 1326L, 9387L, 7245L, 8699L, 27L, 4226L, 
773L, 4122L, 4493L, 6152L, 10112L, 7994L, 6016L, 4234L, 6785L, 
45L, 8811L, 5076L, 562L, 2988L, 5772L, 304L, 9497L, 2160L, 10715L, 
10966L, 10735L, 7436L, 2667L, 10164L, 4289L, 10814L, 4323L, 2904L, 
10038L, 2772L, 8682L, 6495L, 9857L, 2595L, 8384L, 6544L, 9349L, 
997L, 9330L, 10006L, 9314L, 940L, 7118L, 6850L, 3991L, 8228L, 
9704L, 5883L, 6026L, 1359L, 7134L, 5418L, 1653L, 8155L, 439L, 
1397L, 426L, 3942L, 9001L, 39L, 3911L, 4981L, 4717L, 2929L, 7523L, 
2750L, 3119L, 8764L, 10594L, 10903L, 8833L, 7362L, 9574L, 10231L, 
7774L, 1229L, 7618L, 6038L, 6172L, 1011L, 739L, 7394L, 2854L, 
8732L, 8401L, 877L, 3988L, 10357L, 3730L, 6095L, 1600L, 6094L, 
2259L, 9408L, 7976L, 5145L, 2212L, 8161L, 6336L, 4244L, 8724L, 
4211L, 2103L, 6761L, 4554L, 4465L, 7842L, 1895L, 215L, 912L, 
10973L, 4790L, 2618L, 10253L, 4679L, 6570L, 4131L, 10439L, 2070L, 
4831L, 1786L, 943L, 5019L, 7302L, 2916L, 10746L, 467L, 8326L, 
257L, 10661L, 6291L, 7921L, 7169L, 3315L, 1721L, 6624L, 1064L, 
4950L, 7510L, 10691L, 7146L, 6489L, 1644L, 837L, 6400L, 7504L, 
9216L, 9847L, 3053L, 5467L, 2123L, 9266L, 1962L, 2511L, 10652L, 
4706L, 1950L, 5796L, 9877L, 1664L, 38L, 6357L, 5694L, 7470L, 
8727L, 476L, 10849L, 332L, 8362L, 8078L, 7991L, 5191L, 4669L, 
9504L, 3274L, 7378L, 5354L, 5846L, 8381L, 8291L, 1303L, 387L, 
1428L, 9618L, 8957L, 10662L, 10062L, 4097L, 5896L, 4213L, 1642L, 
8115L, 6430L, 6270L, 1917L, 9924L, 7591L, 10367L, 7162L, 8138L, 
5585L, 9843L, 1408L, 1358L, 134L, 4363L, 5667L, 712L, 6594L, 
602L, 10415L, 3191L, 1388L, 5444L, 512L, 10887L, 5457L, 187L, 
6378L, 381L, 1057L, 981L, 5730L, 312L, 8836L, 425L, 10219L, 1930L, 
10101L, 9586L, 1025L, 8842L, 2013L, 1760L, 7562L, 7480L, 10329L, 
2594L, 4507L, 1401L, 10813L, 7764L, 9103L, 570L, 6507L, 2941L, 
7055L, 8599L, 7372L, 7592L, 8313L, 9993L, 4579L, 9072L, 9944L, 
8501L, 3896L, 4773L, 5749L, 2813L, 6019L, 2122L, 2120L, 4720L, 
2608L, 7016L, 6266L, 6708L, 10653L, 2868L, 6317L, 987L, 4202L, 
5595L, 1481L, 2110L, 8939L, 2253L, 9180L, 3214L, 8239L, 103L, 
2952L, 9831L, 3487L, 6722L, 5648L, 10754L, 261L, 7270L, 6090L, 
4030L, 9302L, 2771L, 9464L, 2251L, 10285L, 1905L, 2164L, 6528L, 
1206L, 7303L, 2888L, 10647L, 472L, 4544L, 3780L, 6105L, 2117L, 
7604L, 4577L, 8664L, 8630L, 6807L, 10147L, 5777L, 3120L, 9279L, 
6817L, 5861L, 2345L, 9837L, 1988L, 5741L, 9856L, 8912L, 5838L, 
7072L, 9631L, 5639L, 9817L, 1459L, 6390L, 2534L, 1613L, 9131L, 
8967L, 2992L, 10578L, 1208L, 1269L, 9402L, 2416L, 2571L, 3946L, 
5021L, 10209L, 5108L, 7112L, 7200L, 10271L, 6276L, 10211L, 9664L, 
9822L, 3981L, 7979L, 5785L, 3754L, 7071L, 8612L, 10545L, 7532L, 
859L, 10354L, 10917L, 7954L, 1221L, 3465L, 1081L, 8952L, 1970L, 
9013L, 1385L, 5808L, 3609L, 3252L, 1969L, 7677L, 1110L, 5826L, 
3304L, 9678L, 3514L, 1878L, 10475L, 10629L, 7543L, 4568L, 9976L, 
7801L, 3050L, 838L, 4446L, 2576L, 1777L, 5822L, 2926L, 5054L, 
6981L, 6083L, 1772L, 2365L, 2050L, 3590L, 3591L, 4639L, 765L, 
5086L, 6967L, 7299L, 7529L, 4602L, 1884L, 1123L, 6013L, 9560L, 
1138L, 779L, 8269L, 8660L, 7350L, 7003L, 5007L, 5094L, 2265L, 
8220L, 4422L, 7884L, 200L, 2304L, 3118L, 9568L, 7740L, 8299L, 
858L, 6558L, 487L, 4482L, 547L, 5045L, 7890L, 908L, 2378L, 1792L, 
2876L, 2725L, 5784L, 8601L, 9605L, 5929L, 4492L, 4977L, 8799L, 
8151L, 10571L, 3940L, 4656L, 6784L, 8778L, 2978L, 1133L, 2689L, 
7301L, 6355L, 6905L, 2033L, 2360L, 1188L, 8554L, 10696L, 8144L, 
7541L, 3884L, 10252L, 4573L, 3863L, 2672L, 7186L, 9167L, 3192L, 
7698L, 68L, 7557L, 687L, 6964L, 6584L, 4109L, 10216L, 5415L, 
3948L, 7051L, 7907L, 303L, 10389L, 6124L, 8779L, 7739L, 8065L, 
5384L), class = "data.frame")
```

By running this `ggplot()` function

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), colour="gray", fill="white", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~Var, scales = "free")
```

this plot is created

[image]

However, I would like to paint in every density plot of every facet the quantiles 0.025, 0.5 and 0.0975, following this picture and obtained from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029811/fill-different-colors-for-each-quantile-in-geom-density-of-ggplot).

[image]

In this case, something like this (`probs <- c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975)`) should be created but don't know how to implement inside the plot for every facet.

Any idea?

Comment: Hey @antecessor! I think you might find lots of help here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html. The `ggridges` library colors quantiles automatically.

Comment: Uhmm, I will try, but is there any possibility of doing as described in the question?

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a go and it does *almost* everything you want - `facet_wrap` still works, but you loose the appropriate y-labels. Annoying! Glad you found more help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a plot using the idea you suggested.
As you see my code, it is little tricky.

```
A = ggplot(df, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~Var, scales = "free")

buildA = data.table(ggplot_build(A)$data[[1]])
buildA$Var <- rep(sort(unique(df$Var)),each = 512)
probs <- c(0,0.025, 0.5, 0.975,1)

buildA = buildA %>% group_by(PANEL) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(quant = map(data, ~findInterval(.x$x,quantile(.x$x,probs = probs)))) %>%
  unnest() %>% setDT %>% mutate(quant = factor(quant))

quantRef= buildA %>% group_by(Var) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(quantiles = map(data, ~quantile(.x$density,probs = probs))) %>% select(Var, quantiles)

#colorSet = c('#0FA3B1','#B5E2FA','#F9F7F3','#EDDEA4','#F7A072')
#dev.new()
ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x= value, y= ..density..),colour="gray", fill="white", alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_line(data = buildA, aes(x = x,y = density))+
  geom_ribbon(data = buildA, aes(x=x,ymin =0, ymax= density,fill = quant),alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(guide="none",palette = 'blues')+
  facet_wrap(~Var,scales = "free")
```

[image]

Feel free to ask about my answer.

Comment: It worked keeping the facet_wrap() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was really interesting. I didn't have a smart pipe answer, nor did I use `ggridges`, but here's my take on it:

```
unique(df$Var) %>%
  set_names(., .) %>%
  map(
    ~ {
      df <- df %>% filter(Var == .x)
      dens <- density(df$value)
      data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y) %>%
        mutate(
          quantiles = cut(
            x,
            breaks = quantile(
              x,
              probs = c(0, 0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.975, 1)
            )
          )
        ) %>%
        ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), colour = "gray", fill = "white") +
        geom_line() +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = y, fill = quantiles), alpha = 0.7) +
        scale_fill_brewer(guide = "none") +
        ggtitle(.x)
    }
  ) %>%
  Rmisc::multiplot(plotlist = ., cols = 4)
```

Basically, take the subset by `facet_wrap` variable, make individiual ggplot objects, and gather them into a multiplot by `Rmisc` package.