# How do I create an array formatted string values from quantiles and their values?

Tags: r, plot, quantile

Suppose I am working with some code in R like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=c(1:200),y=rnorm(200))
probs <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9)
quantiles <- quantile(dt$y, prob=probs)
```

I would like to produce a new variable (an array or a sequence) called `labels` that contains formatted strings of the quantiles and their respective values.  Let's say `quantiles` prints out this:

```
> quantiles
       10%        25%        50%        75%        90% 
-1.2097339 -0.6195308 -0.0155171  0.7417443  1.2982685
```

How would I go about programmatically producing `labels` from the value `quantiles` such that when I print out `labels` it emits an array of sequence like this:

```
> labels
[1] "10% at -1.20" "25% at -0.61" "50% at -0.01" "75% at 0.74" "90% at 1.29"
```

So how would you go about wiring all of this together to produce `labels`?  Given that we have `probs`, we could probably simplify this process by doing this zipping with `probs` and `quantiles`'s values.

My goal is to use `labels` to label an density function's x axis with package `ggplot` where I want to elegantly label both the quantiles and their values together ([think about something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864404/686701)).

## Zipping the Data Together

I've seen that I can inspect the quantiles programmatically with the builtin function `names`:

```
> names(quantiles)
[1] "10%" "25%" "50%" "75%" "90%"
```

I've also seen that I can extract the quantile's values programmatically with `as.vector`:

```
> as.vector(quantiles)
[1] -1.2097339 -0.6195308 -0.0155171  0.7417443  1.2982685
```

But I've seen no way of [zipping these two things together à la Python](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

## String Formatting

Then want I decimal precision on the respective quantile values in the formatting, which requires something akin to using `sprintf("%.2f", ...)` on each value.

Each formatted value in the sequence would probably be produced with `sprintf("%s at %.2f", q, v)`.

---

I've used R on and off for two decades, but I've never been able to deeply retain skills in it.  The main problem I am facing is with plumbing and ergonomic wiring together of these two pieces of data.  Through other research, I found something similar to `paste0(names(quantiles), '=', unlist(quantiles), collapse=' at ')`, but this doesn't produce the right result:

```
> paste0(names(quantiles), '=', unlist(quantiles), collapse=' at ')
[1] "10%=-1.20973393089285 at 25%=-0.619530792386393 at 50%=-0.0155171014275248 at 75%=0.741744347748158 at 90%=1.29826846939529"
```

It produces a singular string (instead of a sequence) and the precision of the quantile values is too high.

Comment: You probably want `sep = " at "` in `paste` rather than using the `collapse` argument. Try `paste(names(quantiles), round(quantiles, 2), sep = " at ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sprintf` for everything.

```
> sprintf('%s at %.2f', names(qntls), qntls)
[1] "10% at -1.30" "25% at -0.61" "50% at -0.02" "75% at 0.63"  "90% at 1.29"
```

For the plot you could do sth like this:

```
> par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 1)+.1)
> plot(dens <- density(dt$y), xaxt='n', main='')
> cm <- matrixStats::colMins(dif <- abs(mapply(`-`, list(dens$x), qntls)))
> points(qntls, dens$y[apply(t(t(dif) == cm), 2, which.max)], type='h')
> mtext(sprintf('%s\n(%.2f)', names(qntls), qntls), 1, 1, at=qntls, cex=.8)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> library(data.table)
> set.seed(42)
> dt <- data.table(x=1:200, y=rnorm(200))
> qntls <- quantile(dt$y, prob=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9))
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer.  It's clear I'll need to think in less of a rigid static typing way when using R.  I had read the documentation for [`sprintf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf) before asking this question.  Outside of running the example, which contains `sprintf("%1$d %1$x %1$X", 0:15)`, is there any clue in the `sprintf` documentation that it would return a vector of strings instead of just a scalar string?  Or more fundamentally: is there a R Language API philosophy document I could have read that'd have explained this?

Comment: @mtp Actually in [`sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) (always use original not data-camp or similar) we can read in *Arguments* that it accepts character vectors and _Value_ that it returns character vectors - couldn't find the word *scalar* on that page. Yes, read the official [R-intro](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) and other stuff on  [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/).

Comment: Dumb type system question: wouldn't ` "10% at -1.30" "25% at -0.61" "50% at -0.02" "75% at 0.63"  "90% at 1.29"` from your `sprintf` solution be a *vector of character vectors* and not a character vector?  Namely because one can access its results in an indexed way: `v <- sprintf(...); v[1] /* "10% at -1.30" */; v[2] /* "25% at -0.61" */`?  Sorry for the imprecision in the terminology.  I was thinking about scalar values versus vector.  I don't know what R calls these.

Comment: @mtp Great question, not dumb at all. Indeed the correct terminology would be *vector* *of* *type* *`"character"`* where *character vector* is more usual but kinda shorthand. Unlike e.g. C, where a string `char str[] = "foo";` is an array of characters and we can access elements using `str[0]`, this isn't possible in R where having `x <- "foo"` we need doing `substr(x, 1, 1)` to get the same. Strictly speaking there are no scalars in R, and *x* is still a vector of length 1 (try `length(1)`), and we can do `x[1]` while `x[2]` yields `NA` because there's no second element.