# ggplot2 shade area under density curve by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rnorm(50, mean = 1), rnorm(50, mean = 3))
y <- c(rep("site1", 50), rep("site2", 50))
xy <- data.frame(x, y)
```

And I have made this density plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xy, aes(x, color = y)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

For `site1` I need to shade the area under the curve that > 1% of the data. For `site2` I need to shade the area under the curve that < 75% of the data.

I'm expecting the plot to look something like this (photoshopped). Having been through stack overflow, I'm aware that others have asked how to shade part of the area under a curve, but I cannot figure out how to shade the area under a curve by group.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shading a kernel density plot between two points.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)

Comment: I've looked at that question, but I can't figure out how to shade different areas by group

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one way (and, as @joran says, this is an extension of the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/)):

```
#  same data, just renaming columns for clarity later on
#  also, use data tables
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
value <- c(rnorm(50, mean = 1), rnorm(50, mean = 3))
site  <- c(rep("site1", 50), rep("site2", 50))
dt    <- data.table(site,value)
#  generate kdf
gg <- dt[,list(x=density(value)$x, y=density(value)$y),by="site"]
#  calculate quantiles
q1 <- quantile(dt[site=="site1",value],0.01)
q2 <- quantile(dt[site=="site2",value],0.75)
# generate the plot
ggplot(dt) + stat_density(aes(x=value,color=site),geom="line",position="dodge")+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(gg,site=="site1" & x>q1),
              aes(x=x,ymax=y),ymin=0,fill="red", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(gg,site=="site2" & x<q2),
              aes(x=x,ymax=y),ymin=0,fill="blue", alpha=0.5)
```

Produces this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem with @jlhoward's solution is that you need to manually add `goem_ribbon` for each group you have. I wrote my own `ggplot` stat wrapper following this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html). The benefit of this is that it automatically works with `group_by` and `facet` and you don't need to manually add geoms for each group.

```
StatAreaUnderDensity <- ggproto(
  "StatAreaUnderDensity", Stat,
  required_aes = "x",
  compute_group = function(data, scales, xlim = NULL, n = 50) {
    fun <- approxfun(density(data$x))
    StatFunction$compute_group(data, scales, fun = fun, xlim = xlim, n = n)
  }
)

stat_aud <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "area",
                    position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                    inherit.aes = TRUE, n = 50, xlim=NULL,  
                    ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatAreaUnderDensity, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(xlim = xlim, n = n, ...))
}
```

Now you can use `stat_aud` function just like other ggplot geoms.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rnorm(500, mean = 1), rnorm(500, mean = 3))
y <- c(rep("group 1", 500), rep("group 2", 500))
t_critical = 1.5

tibble(x=x, y=y)%>%ggplot(aes(x=x,color=y))+
  geom_density()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = t_critical)+
  stat_aud(geom="area",
           aes(fill=y),
           xlim = c(0, t_critical), 
              alpha = .2)
```

[image]

```
tibble(x=x, y=y)%>%ggplot(aes(x=x))+
  geom_density()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = t_critical)+
  stat_aud(geom="area",
           fill = "orange",
           xlim = c(0, t_critical), 
              alpha = .2)+
  facet_grid(~y)
```

[image]

Comment: How could I extend this to use different `x_lim` per group based on a variable in my `data.frame`?

Comment: You can read [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot2-ggproto.html) and try to extend the custom layer to accept aesthetics.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use fill.  color controls the outline of the density plot, which is necessary if you want non-black outlines.

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x, color=y, fill = y, alpha=0.4)) + geom_density()
```

To get something like that.  Then you can remove the alpha part of the legend by using

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x, color = y, fill = y, alpha=0.4)) + geom_density()+ guides(alpha='none')
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't get me the plot I need. Note that different areas need to be filled for each group, not the full area under the curve