# Changing color of density plots in ggplot2 based on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have some data I would like to visualize and I am able to make the chart on the left, but I would like to be able to provide more information to the viewer by implementing features like those in the image to the right: shaded based on predefined ranges, and percentage of area in each range. 
[image]

I recognize that this question is similar to these two answers, however I don't understand densities enough to get the dataframe in the correct format:

- [ggplot2 shade area under density curve by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355849/ggplot2-shade-area-under-density-curve-by-group)
- [Shade (fill or color) area under density curve by quantile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189453/shade-fill-or-color-area-under-density-curve-by-quantile)

Here is the code that replicates my example.

If you can, please use dplyr in your response.

Thank you in advance.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
options(scipen = 999)

#Get percentages
  diamonds%>%
    mutate(Cut = cut,
           Prices = cut(price, 
                        breaks=c(0,2499,4999, 19000), 
                        include.lowest=T, dig.lab=10))%>%
    group_by(Cut, Prices)%>%
      summarise(Count = n())%>%
    group_by(Cut)%>%
      mutate(Pct = round(Count/sum(Count), 2))%>%
    ungroup()


#Plot
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price))+
    geom_density(fill="grey50")+
    facet_grid(cut~.)+
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(2500,5000))+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: There is no connection between the `diamonds` data you are piping through the processing steps and the `ggplot` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have density data in the `diamonds` `data.frame`. The other problem that you face is that you need to keep the facet information. I'm not sure how to get `dplyr` to group by `cut` and get `density()`. One can generate summary data as you did but in order to make a density plot you're going to need x,y information for each point.

One workaround I found is making the density plot p like this

```
p<-ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=price))+geom_density()+facet_wrap(~cut,nrow=5)
```

And then ussing ggplot_build function to get the data that is being plotted

```
pg <- ggplot_build(p)
```

This gets you a list where the first element is the actual dataset

```
pg_data<-data.frame(pg$data[[1]],stringsAsFactors = F)
```

You can check that you're interested in y column (which is the same as density) x is going to be the price and PANEL is going to be the facet. I didn't change this to the factor mode with Good, Very Good... but I'm guessing you can.

```
head(pg_data)
              y        x       density    scaled      count    n PANEL group
1 0.00005370272 326.0000 0.00005370272 0.2756038 0.08646139 1610     1    -1
2 0.00005829975 362.1977 0.00005829975 0.2991959 0.09386259 1610     1    -1
3 0.00006307436 398.3953 0.00006307436 0.3236993 0.10154972 1610     1    -1
4 0.00006798165 434.5930 0.00006798165 0.3488836 0.10945045 1610     1    -1
5 0.00007298816 470.7906 0.00007298816 0.3745772 0.11751094 1610     1    -1
6 0.00007807049 506.9883 0.00007807049 0.4006598 0.12569348 1610     1    -1
  ymin          ymax fill weight colour alpha size linetype
1    0 0.00005370272   NA      1  black    NA  0.5        1
2    0 0.00005829975   NA      1  black    NA  0.5        1
3    0 0.00006307436   NA      1  black    NA  0.5        1
4    0 0.00006798165   NA      1  black    NA  0.5        1
5    0 0.00007298816   NA      1  black    NA  0.5        1
6    0 0.00007807049   NA      1  black    NA  0.5        1
```

Now we can plot again everything but using the density data we needed

```
ggplot(data=pg_data,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~PANEL,nrow=5)+geom_area(data=subset(pg_data,x>2499&x<5000),aes(x,y),fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]