# Applying a gradient fill on a density plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to add a gradient fill to a density plot in ggplot2, such that the color in the chart changes along the x-axis? In this example below, the `fill` argument appears to be ignored.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(100)), aes(x = x, fill = x)) + geom_density()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189453/shade-fill-or-color-area-under-density-curve-by-quantile

Comment: @Masoud This answers a different question as it discretizes the scale. I'm not looking to do that.

Comment: Just a suggestion. That's why I did not mark it as dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's always an option to compute density by hand:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- density(x, n = 2^12)
ggplot(data.frame(x = y$x, y = y$y), aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = 0, colour = x)) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'green', high = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: "by hand" being the laborious routed of one extra loc, haha

Answer (score 3):

The ggridges library has your answer.

Here is some reproducible data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

input   = runif(1000, 0, 1)
output  = exp(input) + cos(input)^runif(1000,0,1)
```

Now we need to create a dummy-factor, wrap it all up in a data frame, then label the dummy variable as the factor:

```
name    = rep("Name", length(output))
data    = data.frame(input, output, name)
data$name = as.factor(data$name)
```

From here we can build the density plot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=output, y=name, fill=..x..))+
    geom_density_ridges_gradient()+
    scale_fill_gradient(low="orange", high="navy")
```

Which yields a gradient-filled density plot based on the x-axis values. Of course, from this point you can add/subtract whatever you want on the graph using the ggplot2 library.

[Gradient Filled Density Plot - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QQnx.jpg)