# ggplot2 shade area under curve by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to shade the area under two curves; I want to get exactly the same plots (without thresholds though) as in [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355849/ggplot2-shade-area-under-density-curve-by-group), with the only difference that I want to use `geom_line()` instead of `stat_density()`. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

I've tried what was suggested in that post, but it does not work when I use `geom_line()`. Also, I have tried something different, but this is not quite what I want, as I want to shade using different colors for different groups. Here is the initial code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0,1,0.005)
y1 <- dbeta(x,3,3)
data1<-data.frame('x'=x,'y'=y1)
data1$group<-1

y2 <- dbeta(x,10,4)
data2<-data.frame('x'=x,'y'=y2)
data2$group<-2

data<-rbind(data1, data2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, col=group, fill=group)) +  geom_line(size=1) +geom_ribbon(data=subset(data,x>0 &x<1),aes(x=x,ymax=y),ymin=0, fill="green4",alpha=0.3)
```

In case the above link doesn't work: [ggplot2 shade area under density curve by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355849/ggplot2-shade-area-under-density-curve-by-group)

Comment: And what is missing exactly?

Comment: @YAK The suggested syntax in that previous post does not work when I want to use `geom_line()`.

Comment: When I run your code I get two curves with the area beneath shaded. Do you want them shaded in different colors? then just use `color=as.factor(group)` in the second `aes(` and get rid of `fill="geen4"`...

Comment: OK your solution is almost there. But you override the the group specific coloring by `fill="green4"` and you a continuous (numeric) grouping variable for the color, just use `"1"` and `"2"` instead of `1` and `2`.

Comment: @YAK Yes, I want to be able to choose colors of the shade. But this is very close now to what I wanted.

Comment: use `scale_color_manual`

Comment: @YAK This +`scale_fill_manual(name='', values=c("1" = "green4", "2" = "red"))` allowed to choose shade colors! Thanks Yak for helpful answers!

Comment: Glad you found a solution - don't edit answers in to your question though - it looks like the question still needs answering. Instead, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269825/4975218) looks as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0,1,0.005)
y1 <- dbeta(x,3,3)
data1<-data.frame('x'=x,'y'=y1)
data1$group<-"1"

y2 <- dbeta(x,10,4)
data2<-data.frame('x'=x,'y'=y2)
data2$group<-"2"

data<-rbind(data1, data2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, fill=group)) +
  geom_line(size=.5) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(data,x>0 & x<1),aes(x=x,ymax=y),ymin=0,alpha=0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(name='', values=c("1" = "green4", "2" = "red"))
```

[image]

This is a perfectly fine solution, but I found myself writing similar code over and over, so I wrote `geom_density_line()`. It works like `geom_density()` but draws a line with a filled area instead of a polygon around a filled area. It's part of the current development version of the package ggridges:

```
# current development version is needed for this to work
library(ggridges) # install.github("clauswilke/ggridges")

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, fill=group)) +
  geom_density_line(stat = "identity", size=.5, alpha=0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(name='', values=c("1" = "green4", "2" = "red"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case it might also be useful to someone else, the **solution** was to add `scale_fill_manual()` and change numeric `1` and `2` values in `group` variable into character values `"1"` and `"2"` respectively as follows:

Change `1` to `"1"` and `2` to `"2"` as follows:

```
data1$group<-"1"
data2$group<-"2"
```

and run:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, fill=group)) +
geom_line(size=.5) + 
geom_ribbon(data=subset(data,x>0 & x<1),aes(x=x,ymax=y),ymin=0,alpha=0.3) +
scale_fill_manual(name='', values=c("1" = "green4", "2" = "red"))
```

Comment: This code does not work for me. Please make sure you post code that is free from typos and other errors.

Comment: @Claus Wilke typo has now been corrected, thanks for letting know (and lines rearranged so it can be run straight away, by copy and paste)!