# ggplot histogram with density plot that is filled with color

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have below histogram with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(PF = 10*rnorm(1000))
ggplot(df, aes(x = PF)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..),
                   breaks = seq(-50, 50, by = 10), 
                   colour = "black", 
                   fill = "white") +
stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(df$PF), sd = sd(df$PF)))
```

Now I want to fill the normal density curve with some colour. I tried below without success

```
stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(df$PF), sd = sd(df$PF)), fill = 'red', alpha = 0.50)
```

Is there any way to apply fill colour the area under normal density curve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 shade area under density curve by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355849/ggplot2-shade-area-under-density-curve-by-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `stat_function()` with a non-default geom (here: `geom_ribbon`) and access the y-value generated by `stat_function` with `after_stat()` like this:

```
## ... + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                args = list(mean = mean(df$PF), sd = sd(df$PF)),              
                mapping = aes(x = PF, ymin = 0,
                              ymax = after_stat(y) ## see (1) 
                              ),
                geom = 'ribbon',
                alpha = .5, fill = 'blue'
                )
```

(1) on accessing *computed variables* (stats): https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html