# Visualize the rejection region in a probability distribution curve

Tags: r, statistics

I wish to be able to visualize the rejection area in R for a one- and two-tailed p-value of `0.05` in the following chi-squared density curve:

```
curve(dchisq(x,24), xlim=c(5,50), ylim=c(0,.06))
```

It will also be great if anybody has a generic way to do it for other test statistics as well.

Thanks in advance

Tonio

Comment: Something along these lines? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points

Comment: Excellent examples, and some using just the core libraries. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(HH)
old.omd <- par(omd=c(.05,.88, .05,1))
chisq.setup(df=24)
chisq.curve(df=24, col='blue',alpha=c(0.025,0.025))
chisq.observed(38, df=24)
par(old.omd)
```

Comment: Nice package. I just was wondering how to place the `ylab` to the left of the plot.

Answer (score 6):

An approach using ggplot:

```
df   <- 24
p    <- 0.05
gg   <- data.frame(x=seq(5,50,0.1))
gg$y <- dchisq(gg$x,df)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_path(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_linerange(data=gg[gg$x>qchisq(p,df,lower.tail=F),],
                 aes(x, ymin=0, ymax=y),
                 colour="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution in ggplot2! May I suggest an edit? If you swap `geom_linerange` with `geom_ribbon`  and `color=` with `fill=` you have a more ascetically pleasing result. You can also include the `alpha=` argument to change the transparency of the rejection region if you plan on overlapping density plots.