# ggplot line plot with bars for certain quantiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile

I have this ggplot line plot (actually with two y axis):
[image]

For the Index curve (red line), I would like to add grey horizontal bars for every time period the index exceeds its 0.9 percentile (so when the index is high). So just have to have a guess, this could imply three bars: maybe somewhere between 2002-2003, 2008-2010 and 2011-2012.

I envision these grey bars in the manner produced here: [Adding Shaded region to histogram between quintiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346228/adding-shaded-region-to-histogram-between-quintiles) (so going all the way up from y = 0 to y = max).

I've also tried to learn from the way it was done there, but I'm not able to transfer it to concrete my problem. Would this even be possible with ggplot?

Here is the plot I've created so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Date))
p2 <- p2 + geom_line(aes(y = Count, colour = "Count"),size=1)
p2 <- p2 + geom_line(aes(y = Index, colour = "Index"), size=1)
p2 <- p2 + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1, name = "Index"))
p2 <- p2 + scale_colour_manual(values = c("#56B4E9", "#CC6666"))
p2 <- p2 + labs(y = "Count", x = "", colour = "") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=20, hjust=0.5))
p2
```

Here is the code for reproduction:

```
   data<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(959817600, 962409600, 965088000, 
967766400, 970358400, 973036800, 975628800, 978307200, 980985600, 
983404800, 986083200, 988675200, 991353600, 993945600, 996624000, 
999302400, 1001894400, 1004572800, 1007164800, 1009843200, 1012521600, 
1014940800, 1017619200, 1020211200, 1022889600, 1025481600, 1028160000, 
1030838400, 1033430400, 1036108800, 1038700800, 1041379200, 1044057600, 
1046476800, 1049155200, 1051747200, 1054425600, 1057017600, 1059696000, 
1062374400, 1064966400, 1067644800, 1070236800, 1072915200, 1075593600, 
1078099200, 1080777600, 1083369600, 1086048000, 1088640000, 1091318400, 
1093996800, 1096588800, 1099267200, 1101859200, 1104537600, 1107216000, 
1109635200, 1112313600, 1114905600, 1117584000, 1120176000, 1122854400, 
1125532800, 1128124800, 1130803200, 1133395200, 1136073600, 1138752000, 
1141171200, 1143849600, 1146441600, 1149120000, 1151712000, 1154390400, 
1157068800, 1159660800, 1162339200, 1164931200, 1167609600, 1170288000, 
1172707200, 1175385600, 1177977600, 1180656000, 1183248000, 1185926400, 
1188604800, 1191196800, 1193875200, 1196467200, 1199145600, 1201824000, 
1204329600, 1207008000, 1209600000, 1212278400, 1214870400, 1217548800, 
1220227200, 1222819200, 1225497600, 1228089600, 1230768000, 1233446400, 
1235865600, 1238544000, 1241136000, 1243814400, 1246406400, 1249084800, 
1251763200, 1254355200, 1257033600, 1259625600, 1262304000, 1264982400, 
1267401600, 1270080000, 1272672000, 1275350400, 1277942400, 1280620800, 
1283299200, 1285891200, 1288569600, 1291161600, 1293840000, 1296518400, 
1298937600, 1301616000, 1304208000, 1306886400, 1309478400, 1312156800, 
1314835200, 1317427200, 1320105600, 1322697600, 1325376000, 1328054400, 
1330560000, 1333238400, 1335830400, 1338508800, 1341100800, 1343779200, 
1346457600, 1349049600, 1351728000, 1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 
1362096000, 1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 
1377993600, 1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 
1393632000, 1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 
1409529600, 1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 
1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 
1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 
1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 
1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 
1488326400, 1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Count = c(35, 42, 67, 25, 23, 22, 
8, 3, 9, 8, 3, 10, 15, 8, 5, 0, 8, 13, 12, 1, 9, 7, 8, 15, 9, 
6, 1, 0, 10, 10, 6, 0, 4, 1, 0, 2, 3, 7, 7, 6, 12, 16, 22, 5, 
19, 16, 12, 15, 28, 28, 17, 15, 31, 16, 30, 9, 25, 7, 10, 14, 
27, 23, 35, 17, 17, 20, 22, 16, 22, 17, 21, 17, 20, 10, 9, 15, 
26, 28, 36, 10, 18, 16, 17, 34, 24, 20, 16, 7, 33, 38, 23, 12, 
7, 5, 5, 7, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 6, 2, 5, 8, 14, 
12, 7, 6, 8, 13, 14, 14, 11, 11, 12, 7, 22, 21, 21, 7, 19, 8, 
21, 24, 13, 16, 4, 0, 3, 17, 11, 3, 19, 22, 18, 12, 4, 12, 7, 
8, 24, 9, 8, 11, 9, 14, 14, 28, 19, 19, 20, 22, 32, 29, 13, 18, 
23, 29, 29, 21, 31, 36, 14, 14, 32, 26, 15, 10, 15, 5, 14, 19, 
26, 22, 10, 6, 16, 12, 2, 0, 5, 4, 7, 15, 7, 13, 8, 17, 21, 2, 
7, 9, 8, 13, 20, 20, 21), Index = c(21.54, 19.9216666666667, 
18.0886956521739, 19.6392857142857, 25.2, 26.4043181818182, 26.6071428571429, 
25.0708695652174, 23.41125, 28.4968181818182, 28.0430952380952, 
22.875652173913, 20.9404761904762, 22.1884090909091, 21.8617391304348, 
34.92825, 32.7213043478261, 26.4986363636364, 23.6597619047619, 
22.3317391304348, 22.902, 18.9411904761905, 19.9004545454545, 
20.0667391304348, 25.271, 33.7980434782609, 33.7427272727273, 
37.5835714285714, 35.2430434782609, 28.1369047619048, 28.1522727272727, 
27.3721739130435, 32.20075, 30.6342857142857, 23.8888636363636, 
20.2095454545455, 20.3623809523809, 19.1858695652174, 19.2742857142857, 
19.5002272727273, 18.0234782608696, 17.34475, 16.8363043478261, 
16.1540909090909, 15.973, 17.6873913043478, 15.7018181818182, 
17.6190476190476, 15.3661363636364, 15.5097727272727, 16.6840909090909, 
14.0768181818182, 14.9738095238095, 13.5395454545455, 12.4258695652174, 
13.3909523809524, 11.7315, 13.1463043478261, 14.4590476190476, 
13.9109090909091, 11.8686363636364, 11.072380952381, 12.9513043478261, 
12.6563636363636, 14.937619047619, 12.0918181818182, 11.2445454545455, 
11.9952272727273, 12.458, 11.6939130434783, 11.879, 14.5417391304348, 
16.9186363636364, 15.2438095238095, 13.3517391304348, 12.1897619047619, 
11.3063636363636, 10.8002272727273, 10.9809523809524, 11.0823913043478, 
11.104, 15.1627272727273, 12.945, 13.3036956521739, 14.947619047619, 
17.1790909090909, 25.0260869565217, 22.243, 19.115652173913, 
25.6115909090909, 21.5071428571429, 25.8291304347826, 25.4488095238095, 
27.0592857142857, 21.5627272727273, 18.3620454545455, 22.1104761904762, 
24.3630434782609, 20.6957142857143, 29.8331818181818, 61.1773913043478, 
62.2625, 52.0306521739131, 44.7561363636364, 45.58175, 44.7954545454545, 
38.0231818181818, 31.9611904761905, 29.1404545454545, 26.2632608695652, 
25.3371428571429, 24.95, 24.2522727272727, 23.7276190476191, 
21.1726086956522, 20.5154761904762, 22.5375, 17.7673913043478, 
17.4161363636364, 32.0188095238095, 29.9163636363636, 25.7615909090909, 
24.7459090909091, 22.5193181818182, 20.3733333333333, 20.1318181818182, 
17.5478260869565, 17.2369047619048, 17.48925, 20.7234782608696, 
16.1957142857143, 16.8570454545455, 19.1531818181818, 19.0721428571429, 
35.0291304347826, 36.4813636363636, 32.8290476190476, 32.0456818181818, 
24.8781818181818, 20.4227272727273, 18.3997619047619, 16.1672727272727, 
17.8197619047619, 21.0189130434783, 21.1309523809524, 17.5431818181818, 
15.6895652173913, 15.40675, 16.4439130434783, 16.6347727272727, 
17.3714285714286, 13.5828260869565, 13.98825, 13.0366666666667, 
13.9672727272727, 13.5258695652174, 17.2715, 14.0428260869565, 
14.21, 14.7928571428571, 15.4078260869565, 12.9438095238095, 
14.1111363636364, 14.1604347826087, 15.3825, 14.8366666666667, 
14.1575, 12.4279545454545, 11.5414285714286, 12.2323913043478, 
13.4919047619048, 13.4052272727273, 18.0586956521739, 13.3775, 
16.2115217391304, 19.1502272727273, 15.87125, 14.8127272727273, 
13.5497727272727, 13.3269047619048, 14.3395454545455, 14.4634782608696, 
19.4280952380952, 24.4668181818182, 16.7895454545455, 16.1597619047619, 
17.9515217391304, 23.6490476190476, 22.6235714285714, 15.8117391304348, 
14.3004761904762, 14.7984090909091, 17.7745454545455, 13.2545238095238, 
12.3995652173913, 14.1186363636364, 14.5852380952381, 15.1065909090909, 
12.4379545454545, 11.6893181818182, 11.5305, 11.8978260869565, 
13.245, 10.8289130434783, 10.5136363636364)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Count", "Index"), row.names = c(NA, -205L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible approach by first generating on which date's the horizontal bars should be present:

```
df3 <- df
df3$quant <- ifelse(df$Index > quantile(df$Index, 0.9), 1, 0)
```

and then by grouping the data based on runs of same values.

```
df3$group <- rep(1:length(rle(df3$quant)$lengths), times = rle(df3$quant)$lengths)
```

Or using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(quant = ifelse(Index > quantile(Index, 0.9), 1, 0),
         group = rep(1:length(rle(quant)$lengths), times = rle(quant)$lengths)) -> df2
```

In `geom_ribbon` just subset the data so only Date's with `quant == 1` are plotted and use the groupings obtained by `rle` calls to limit the ranges of ribbons.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(df2, quant == 1),
              aes(x = Date, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, group = group), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Count, colour = "Count"), size=1)+
  geom_line(aes(y = Index, colour = "Index"), size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1, name = "Index")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#56B4E9", "#CC6666")) +
  labs(y = "Count", x = "", colour = "") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the type of bars I was looking for! Thank you very much! I have got some questions while trying to unterstand your approach: 1) Already in the first line (ifelse(Index > quantile(.$Index, 0.9), 1, 0)), you use a dot. Did you save the dataset under a dot before (. <- data)? Or what it the meaning of the dots? 2) I guess you saved the first line of code under quant (quant <- ifelse(..))?

Comment: 3) I have read that %>% is used to express different functions "next to each other" instead of writing them in a nested way. But what would be the nested version in this case? When I try to run this part of code, I get the message "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : wrong result size (205), expected 512 or 1". I am not sure what it says.

Comment: @SCW16  Edited post. I have changed the first part (which was unreproducible code) to the base R approach. After that there is the `tidyverse` approach. You will find `df2 == df3`. The pipe `%>%` is used to pipe the data as the first argument of a function in the next call, if the data should not be in the first position one can refer to it with a `.` So after a pipe `.$Index` is equivalent to `df$Index`. Anyway in this particular case it was not needed at all because the function `mutate` assumes all named variables are from the data. I have removed it. Check if it is reproducible please.

Comment: It works indeed! Thank you for your constructive help!