# Shading a kernel density estimate between two points - with transparency

Tags: r, graphics, histogram

So I like this answer: [Shading a kernel density plot between two points.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)

But I want to extend the question.

Here is what I have right now, and I am not satisfied.

[image]

I want to make the rectangles partially see-through (transparent, alpha).

How do I do that?

For those who are curious the x-label is an AIC difference.

Comment: Did you consider Ben Bolker's answer on the page that you have linked?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ggplot2 library.  I failed to see the "alpha" - miss on my part.  I was using JD Long's answer.