# How can I color the area below several normal distributions?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

After several tries, I finally could obtained a unique figure with several normal distributions. In those distributions, the 1sd was also drawn as vertical rectangles. The code I used is this one:

```
x1<-50:200
a1<-dnorm(x1,134,20)
b1<-dnorm(x1,130,14)
c1<-dnorm(x1,132,12)
d1<-dnorm(x1,105,10)

scale<-range(pretty(range(a1,b1,c1,d1)))

remap<-function(x, to, from=range(x)) {
    (x-from[1]) / (from[2]-from[1]) * (to[2]-to[1]) + to[1] 
}

plot(NA, NA, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", type="n", xlim=scale, ylim=scale, xlab="Variable X", ylab="")
rect(remap(134-20, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(134+20, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#ff606025")
rect(remap(130-14, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(130+14, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#005ccd40")
rect(remap(132-12, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(132+12, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#005ccd40")
rect(remap(105-10, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(105+10, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#005ccd40")
#R1429
rect(remap(183, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(183, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="darkblue", lwd=3,lty=3)

lines(remap(x1,scale), a1, col="#ff6060", lwd=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), b1, col="#005ccd", lwd=3, lty=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), c1, col="#005ccd", lwd=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), d1, col="#005ccd", lwd=3,lty=3)

axis(2);
axis(1, at=remap(pretty(x1), scale), pretty(x1))
```

I got the next figure after running the code:
[image]

But my question is: how can I color only the area below each normal distribution, instead of doing vertical rectangles?

It would be much easier to interpret.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points should get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another version using `ggvis`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

## -- data generation copied from @NickK -- ##
data.frame(group = letters[1:4],
           m = c(130, 134, 132, 105),
           s = c(20, 14, 12, 10)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(data_frame(group = .$group,
                x = 50:200,
                y = dnorm(x, .$m, .$s),
                withinSd = abs(x - .$m) <= .$s)) %>%
## ---------------------------------------- ##
  mutate(dash = ifelse(grepl("a|d", group), 5, 0),
         color = ifelse(grepl("a|c|d", group), "blue", "red"))  %>%
  ggvis() %>%
  layer_paths(~x, ~y, stroke := ~color, strokeDash := ~dash) %>%
  filter(withinSd) %>%
  layer_ribbons(~x, ~y, y2 = ~y-y, fill := ~color, fillOpacity := 0.2) %>%
  hide_legend("fill") %>%
  add_axis("y", title_offset = 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steven. Maybe I've been misinterpreted and didn't write explicity what I wanted. The area below the curve I want to be colored is only the area comprised between 1sd and not the full area. Has it any easy solution in the code?

Answer (score 3):

You can fill in under curves by using `polygon`.

```
## Some distributions
x1 <- 50:200
means <- c(134, 130, 132, 105)
sds <- c(20, 14, 12, 10)
dists <- lapply(seq_along(means), function(i) dnorm(x1, means[i], sds[i]))

## Some colors
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))(length(dists))

## Blank plot
plot(c(x1[1], x1[length(x1)]), c(min(unlist(dists)), max(unlist(dists))), 
     type="n", xlab="X", ylab="Density")

## Add polygons
for (i in seq_along(dists))
    polygon(c(x1, rev(x1)), 
            c(numeric(length(x1)), rev(dists[[i]])), 
            col=cols[i],
            density=40)
```

[image]

### Edit: for polygons within 1sd

```
xs <- sapply(seq_along(dists), function(i)  # get supports on x1
    do.call(`:`, as.list(which(x1 %in% (means[i] + c(-1,1)*sds[i])))))

plot(range(x1), range(unlist(dists)), type="n", xlab="X", ylab="Density")
for (i in seq_along(dists)) {
    x <- x1[xs[[i]]]
    polygon(c(x, rev(x)), 
            c(numeric(length(x)), rev(dists[[i]][xs[[i]]])), 
            col=cols[i],
            density=40)
    points(x1, dists[[i]], type="l", lty=2, col=cols[i])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Legalizelt. Maybe I've been misinterpreted and didn't write explicity what I wanted. The area below the curve I want to be colored is only the area comprised between 1sd and not the full area. Has it any easy solution in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of doing it using some of Hadley Wickham's packages:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyr")
data.frame(x = 50:200) %>%
  mutate(a = dnorm(x,134,20),
         b = dnorm(x,130,14),
         c = dnorm(x,132,12),
         d = dnorm(x,105,10)) %>%
  gather(group, y, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = group)) %>%
  + geom_area(alpha = 0.3, position = "identity") %>%
  + geom_line() %>%
  print
```

[image: output with 4 normal distributions]

Here's a version filling only within 1 SD:

```
data.frame(group = letters[1:4],
  m = c(130, 134, 132, 105),
  s = c(20, 14, 12, 10)
) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(data_frame(group = .$group,
    x = 50:200,
    y = dnorm(x, .$m, .$s),
    withinSd = abs(x - .$m) <= .$s)
  ) %>% {
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_area(aes(fill = group), filter(., withinSd),
        position = "identity", alpha = 0.3) +
      guides(colour = "none")
    }
```

[image: Graph with 1 SD]

If you wanted the graphs to all be the same height, you could just add a bit of extra `dplyr` magic:

```
data.frame(group = letters[1:4],
           m = c(130, 134, 132, 105),
           s = c(20, 14, 12, 10)
) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(data_frame(group = .$group,
                x = 50:200,
                y = dnorm(x, .$m, .$s),
                withinSd = abs(x - .$m) <= .$s)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(y = y / max(y)) %>%
  {
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_area(aes(fill = group), filter(., withinSd),
                position = "identity", alpha = 0.3) +
      guides(colour = "none")
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick K. Maybe I've been misinterpreted and didn't write explicity what I wanted. The area below the curve I want to be colored is only the area comprised between 1sd and not the full area. Has it any easy solution in the code?

Comment: @NickK Very nice data generation technique ! I reused it for my post.

Comment: Is there any possibility to control the width and height of the different normal distributions by using sample size? I mean, I want to display as well +-2 sd and I realized than when using 1 or 2 sd the sizes are different. How could it be possibly solved?

Comment: @antecessor just added another example which scales each of the groups to the maximum within the group

Answer (score 3):

Here's another version using base R.  This one uses the `type='h'` option in `lines()` to draw a lot of vertical lines, so many that it ends up shading the region.  Note that this required increasing the number of sample points in `x1` (try changing `x1` back to `50:200` to see what happens).

```
x1 <- seq(50,200,length=1000)
a1 <- dnorm(x1,134,20)
b1 <- dnorm(x1,130,14)
c1 <- dnorm(x1,132,12)
d1 <- dnorm(x1,105,10)

dists <- list(a1,b1,c1,d1)

# specify color names then convert them to RGB+alpha values
col <- c("red","green","blue","yellow")
col.rgba <- rgb(t(col2rgb(col))/255, alpha=0.2)

plot(NA, NA, xlim=range(x1), ylim=range(unlist(dists)), xlab="Variable X", ylab="")

# loop through each distribution
for (i in 1:length(dists)) {
  lines(x1, dists[[i]], type='h', lwd=2, col=col.rgba[i]) # add shaded region
  lines(x1, dists[[i]], type='l') # add solid line at top
}
```

Here's the output:

[image: a busy cat]