# polygon plot is not showing up passing in x and y coordinates

Tags: r

I'd like to color the triangular region here under the line that you see so I pass in the vector of x coordinates and y coordinates BUT the region is not shading in.

can you get the region under the line shaded red? the bottom of the region is the x axis and the top is the line. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
  x = c(0,1)
   y = c(1,2)
   x
   y
   plot(x,y)
   polygon(x, y, col="red")
```

Comment: you pass only two x,y coordinates to polygon, so it will only shade the "area" enclosed within what is effectively a straight line - which has no area to shade.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points for explanation of how to shade under a curve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shading a kernel density plot between two points.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)

Answer (score 0):

A triangle has three points. Your `x` and `y` vectors only describe two points.

The `polygon()` function can draw any triangle or higher-order polygon, but you have to fully define the polygon by passing all of its vertices in the `x` and `y` arguments.

We can solve the problem by supplementing the `x` and `y` vectors with an additional element that fills in the missing vertex when passing these vectors to the `polygon()` function.

Since you've indicated you want to shade the area *under* the line, here's how I would do this:

- First I'll address the additional `y` coordinate, since it's easier. We simply need to use the minimum of the known `y` coordinates, for which we can use `min()`.
- For `x`, we need to copy the `x` coordinate that corresponds to the vertex with the *higher* y-coordinate, for which we can use `which.max()` on `y` and then subscripting `x`.

---

```
x <- c(0,1);
y <- c(1,2);
plot(x,y);
polygon(c(x,x[which.max(y)]),c(y,min(y)),col='red');
```

[image: plot]