# Fully cover a cylindrical area between two curves

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how to fully cover a cylindrical area between two curves using some color? Right now, I've tried using `rect()` but there remain **two tiny white spaces** above and below the `rect()` that I don't know how to cover?

Here **is my current R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x), -1.96, 1.96, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
curve(-dnorm(x), -1.96, 1.96, add=TRUE)

rect(-.5, -dnorm(-.5), .5, dnorm(.5), col="red" )  # How can I fill-up the white space 
                                                   # above and below the rectangle?
axis(1, at=c(-1.96,0,1.96),mgp=c(2, .6, .45), tcl=F )
```

Also, Here is a picture showing the top white space and the bottom white space:

[image]

Comment: What spaces are you talking about? Can you add an image to make it more clear?

Comment: Whoa, your code is not producing that at all. Is there something you're not telling us? (My answer still applies in concept, though you'll need to adjust it for your mirroring.)

Comment: Have you looked at other answers about filling areas under curves? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line at the bottom is fixable by adding `line=0` to `axis()`. (I find the documentation at `?axis` to imply that the default `line=NA` will place the line at the margin vice "number of lines into the margin".

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but you cannot fill the top white space with a rectangle. TO follow the curvature at the top of the curve, you need `polygon`:

```
curve(dnorm(x), -1.96, 1.96, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
curve(-dnorm(x), -1.96, 1.96, add=TRUE)
n <- 50
xs <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, len=n)
polygon(c(xs[1], xs, xs[n]), c(0, dnorm(xs), 0), col='red')
axis(1, at=c(-1.96,0,1.96),mgp=c(2, .6, .45), tcl=F , line = 0)
```

[image: normal curve]

Comment: I thought the single function call would be self-evident, but I'm using *your code* to start this plot. Take a look at [`?polygon`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/polygon.html) for further explanation.

Comment: No, you can do it one. Just think of a `polygon` as a call to `lines` that wraps-around to the starting point and optionally colors the inner space. There are plenty of examples on SO (as well as the examples within `?polygon` that clearly exhaust the options).

Comment: StackOverflow, you might have heard of it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(-1.96,1.96,0.01)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, xlim=c(-1.96, 1.96))+
  stat_function(fun=function(x)-dnorm(x), xlim=c(-1.96, 1.96))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-.5, xmax=.5,ymin=-dnorm(.5), ymax=dnorm(.5)), fill='red', col='black', alpha=0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x=c(0.00,-1.96,1.96), y=rep(0,3)), aes(x=x, y=y, label = x), nudge_y = 0.015) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]