# How to shade under part of a line from a dataset

Tags: r

I have a simple plot of same data from an experiment.

```
plot(x=sample95$PositionA, y=sample95$AbsA, xlab=expression(position (mm)), ylab=expression(A[260]), type='l')
```

[image]
I would like to shade a particular area under the line, let's say from 35-45mm. From what I've searched so far, I think I need to use the polygon function, but I'm unsure how to assign vertices from a big dataset like this. Every example I've seen so far uses a normal curve.

Any help is appreciated, I am very new to R/RStudio!

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points) didn't help?

Comment: have a look to provide example data and write good question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse` tools including `ggplot2`. I use the built in `airquality` dataset as an example.

This first part is just to put the data in a format that we can plot by combining the month and the day into a single date. You can just substitute `date` for `PositionA` in your data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- airquality %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(str_to_lower(colnames(.))) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(str_c("1973-", month, "-", day)))
```

This is the plot code. In `ggplot2`, we start with the function `ggplot()` and add `geom` functions to it with `+` to create the plot in layers.

The first function, `geom_line`, joins up all observations in the order that they appear based on the `x` variable, so it makes the line  that we see. Each `geom` needs a particular `mapping` to an aesthetic, so here we want `date` on the x axis and `temp` on the y axis, so we write `aes(x = date, y = temp)`.

The second function, `geom_ribbon`, is designed to plot bands at particular `x` values between a `ymax` and a `ymin`. This lets us shade the area underneath the line by choosing a constant `ymin = 55` (a value lower than the minimum temperature) and setting `ymax = temp`.

We shade a specific part of the chart by specifying the `data` argument. Normally `geom` functions act on the dataset *inherited* from `ggplot()`, but you can override them by specifying individually. Here we use `filter` to only plot the points where the `date` is in June in `geom_ribbon`.

```r
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = temp)) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = filter(df, date < as.Date("1973-07-01") & date > as.Date("1973-06-01")),
    mapping = aes(x = date, ymax = temp, ymin = 55)
    )
```

This gives the chart below:

[image]

Created on 2018-02-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).