# Using curve() and dnorm() to overlay histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram, curve, normal-distribution

I need to overlay a normal distribution on a histogram using `curve()` and `dnorm()`. `dnorm` should not have the parameters of my data, but be a generalized normal distribution with mean = 0 and sd = 5.

Using this site and a lot of tutorials, I would expect the code to be

```
hist(mtcars$mpg)
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 5), add= TRUE, col="red")
```

But all I get is a flat line. If I use a stand alone example, leaving out `add=TRUE` I get the desired density function:

```
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 5), col="red")
```

Does anyone have any idea what mistake I am making?

Comment: probably a duplicate, but try `hist(..., freq=FALSE)`

Comment: What is `x`? Can you provide a reproducible example (i.e., all the code needed to get to to your problem)?

Comment: freq=FALSE hasn't changed anything.

x is part of curve(), so the example I gave is reproducible and the shortest version of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the range of the data (10-35), there is very little probability in the Normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a SD of 5 (i.e. the curve *starts* about at the upper end of the 95% confidence interval of the distribution).

If we add `freq= FALSE` to the `hist()` call (as is appropriate if you want to compare a probability distribution to the histogram), we can see a little bit of the red curve at the beginning (you could also multiply by a constant if you  want the tail to be more visible). (Distribution shown for a more plausible value of the mean as well [blue line].)

```r
## png("tmp.png"); par(las=1, bty="l")
hist(mtcars$mpg, freq=FALSE)
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 5), add = TRUE, col = "red")
curve(dnorm(x, 20, 5), add = TRUE, col = "blue")
## dev.off()
```

[image]

Graphically, this might be clearer/more noticeable if you [shaded the area under the Normal distribution curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)

Comment: Ah, I made some mistake with the freq=FALSE
Thank you a lot! It was really beginning to drive me mad.