# Shade are under a curve with polygon in RStudio

Tags: r

This is the plot x and y axis

```
xDM<- seq(0, 2*mean1, 0.1)

yDMedia<- dnorm(xDM, mean1, standarD/sqrt(n))
```

This is my attempt to shade the area from 6 to 0 under the plot curve

```
 polygon(c(xDM[xDM<=6], max(xDM), 6), c(yDM[xDM<=6], 0, 0), col="red")
```

[image: The result]

The blue dashed line is where I want the polygon to finish, I can't see where I'm doing bad the axis of the shade in the polygon function

Comment: You are close, try `polygon(c(xDM[xDM<=6], 6, max(xDM)), c(yDM[xDM<=6], 0, 0), col="red")`

Comment: You might also find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points.